# Reading binary file and looping over each byte

Tags: python, file-io, binary

In Python, how do I read in a binary file and loop over each byte of that file?

Comment: Reading a byte at a time is a special case of reading a chunk at a time, for chunk size equal to 1.

Answer (score 477, accepted):

### Python >= 3.8

Thanks to the [walrus operator (`:=`)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) the solution is quite short. We read `bytes` objects from the file and assign them to the variable `byte`

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    while (byte := f.read(1)):
        # Do stuff with byte.
```

### Python >= 3

In older Python 3 versions, we get have to use a slightly more verbose way:

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != b"":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
```

Or as benhoyt says, skip the not equal and take advantage of the fact that `b""` evaluates to false. This makes the code compatible between 2.6 and 3.x without any changes. It would also save you from changing the condition if you go from byte mode to text or the reverse.

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte:
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
```

### Python >= 2.5

In Python 2, it's a bit different. Here we don't get bytes objects, but raw characters:

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
```

Note that the with statement is not available in versions of Python below 2.5. To use it in v 2.5 you'll need to import it:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

In 2.6 this is not needed.

### Python 2.4 and Earlier

```
f = open("myfile", "rb")
try:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Reading a file byte-wise is a performance nightmare. This cannot be the best solution available in python. This code should be used with care.

Comment: @usr: Well the file objects are buffered internally, and even so this is what was asked for. Not every script needs optimal performance.

Comment: @usr Totally agree: reading bytewise is a waste of cycles. The codeape solution looks better.

Comment: @mezhaka: So you change it from read(1) to read(bufsize) and in the while-loop you do a for-in... the example still stands.

Comment: @usr: the performance difference can be as much as 200 times [for the code I've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20014805/4279).

Comment: In Python 2.7.11 the code in this answer is about 4.5 times **slower** than what's in [@codeape's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1035456/355230), and in Python 3.5.1 it's roughly 2.9 times slower (reading a 128K test file of random byte values).

Comment: Seems to jump the first byte.

Comment: @usr - it depends on how many bytes you want to process.  If they are few enough, "badly" performing but easily understandable code can be much preferred.  The waste of CPU cycles is compensated for saving "reader CPU cycles" when maintaing the code.

Comment: @PedroLobito Remember to put your code between the `while byte:` and the `byte = f.read(1)` at the end. There's a comment there that says `# Do stuff with byte.` where you do stuff with byte.

Comment: In Python 3.8: `while byte := f.read(1): "do stuff with byte"` ([The Walrus Operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html?highlight=walrus#assignment-expressions))

Comment: @jfs: Using the walrus operator reduces the number of lines of code, but code using it runs at about the same speed or a little slower than not, according to my timing tests running Python 3.8.0 — and @ codeape's and @ Vinay Sajip's answers are both still significantly faster.

Comment: @martineau: this answer is not about performance. My suggestion is not about the number of lines, it is about readability.

Comment: @jfs: That's all well and nice, but in the real world performance and being able to work in a version of Python < 3.8.0 could be more important — which is what my comment is about.

Answer (score 194):

This generator yields bytes from a file, reading the file in chunks:

```
def bytes_from_file(filename, chunksize=8192):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunksize)
            if chunk:
                for b in chunk:
                    yield b
            else:
                break

# example:
for b in bytes_from_file('filename'):
    do_stuff_with(b)
```

See the Python documentation for information on [iterators](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and [generators](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).

Comment: @codeape Just what I am looking for. But, how do you determine chunksize? Can it be an arbitrary value?

Comment: @swdev: The example uses a chunksize of 8192 *Bytes*. The parameter for the file.read()-function simply specifies the size, i.e. the number of Bytes to be read. codeape chose `8192 Byte = 8 kB` (actually it's `KiB` but that's not as commonly known). The value is "totally" random but 8 kB seems to be an appropriate value: not too much memory is wasted and still there are not "too many" read operations as in the accepted answer by Skurmedel...

Comment: It has been sometimes, but I think I eventually use an arbitrary number too. It works :)

Comment: The filesystem already buffers chunks of data, so this code is redundant.  It's better to read a byte at a time.

Comment: While already faster than the accepted answer, this could be sped-up by another 20-25% by replacing the entire inner-most `for b in chunk:` loop with `yield from chunk`. This form of `yield` was added in Python 3.3 (see [_Yield Expressions_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)).

Comment: @stack: What you say about it being redundant doing it this way does not appear to be true in actual timing tests I have run comparing this approach to that's in Skurmedel's answer.

Comment: This is slower for me than the accepted answer. I have no idea why.

Comment: This is slow because the "chunks" are optimizing the wrong thing: reading the file. That's already optimized by the operating system. If your  particular `do_stuff_with(b)` function doesn't do much either then most of the time is spent calling `bytes_from_file()` *once per byte*. I verified this with some basic profiling.

Comment: The yield expressions have been deprecated in 3.7

Comment: Hmm seems unlikely, link?

Comment: @ShellZero: I, too, have *strong* doubts that `yield` expressions are going away. — codeape: You might be interested in the [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013806/355230) I just posted.

Comment: "Yield expressions (both yield and yield from clauses) are now deprecated in comprehensions and generator expressions", not in general

Answer (score 62):

If the file is not too big that holding it in memory is a problem:

```
with open("filename", "rb") as f:
    bytes_read = f.read()
for b in bytes_read:
    process_byte(b)
```

where process_byte represents some operation you want to perform on the passed-in byte.

If you want to process a chunk at a time:

```
with open("filename", "rb") as f:
    bytes_read = f.read(CHUNKSIZE)
    while bytes_read:
        for b in bytes_read:
            process_byte(b)
        bytes_read = f.read(CHUNKSIZE)
```

The `with` statement is available in Python 2.5 and greater.

Comment: You might be interested in the [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013806/355230) I just posted.

Answer (score 45):

> ### Reading binary file in Python and looping over each byte

New in Python 3.5 is the `pathlib` module, which has a convenience method specifically to read in a file as bytes, allowing us to iterate over the bytes. I consider this a decent (if quick and dirty) answer:

```
import pathlib

for byte in pathlib.Path(path).read_bytes():
    print(byte)
```

Interesting that this is the only answer to mention `pathlib`.

In Python 2, you probably would do this (as Vinay Sajip also suggests):

```
with open(path, 'b') as file:
    for byte in file.read():
        print(byte)
```

In the case that the file may be too large to iterate over in-memory, you would chunk it, idiomatically, using the `iter` function with the `callable, sentinel` signature - the Python 2 version:

```
with open(path, 'b') as file:
    callable = lambda: file.read(1024)
    sentinel = bytes() # or b''
    for chunk in iter(callable, sentinel): 
        for byte in chunk:
            print(byte)
```

(Several other answers mention this, but few offer a sensible read size.)

### Best practice for large files or buffered/interactive reading

Let's create a function to do this, including idiomatic uses of the standard library for Python 3.5+:

```
from pathlib import Path
from functools import partial
from io import DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE

def file_byte_iterator(path):
    """given a path, return an iterator over the file
    that lazily loads the file
    """
    path = Path(path)
    with path.open('rb') as file:
        reader = partial(file.read1, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        file_iterator = iter(reader, bytes())
        for chunk in file_iterator:
            yield from chunk
```

Note that we use `file.read1`. `file.read` blocks until it gets all the bytes requested of it or `EOF`. `file.read1` allows us to avoid blocking, and it can return more quickly because of this. No other answers mention this as well.

#### Demonstration of best practice usage:

Let's make a file with a megabyte (actually mebibyte) of pseudorandom data:

```
import random
import pathlib
path = 'pseudorandom_bytes'
pathobj = pathlib.Path(path)

pathobj.write_bytes(
  bytes(random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(2**20)))
```

Now let's iterate over it and materialize it in memory:

```
>>> l = list(file_byte_iterator(path))
>>> len(l)
1048576
```

We can inspect any part of the data, for example, the last 100 and first 100 bytes:

```
>>> l[-100:]
[208, 5, 156, 186, 58, 107, 24, 12, 75, 15, 1, 252, 216, 183, 235, 6, 136, 50, 222, 218, 7, 65, 234, 129, 240, 195, 165, 215, 245, 201, 222, 95, 87, 71, 232, 235, 36, 224, 190, 185, 12, 40, 131, 54, 79, 93, 210, 6, 154, 184, 82, 222, 80, 141, 117, 110, 254, 82, 29, 166, 91, 42, 232, 72, 231, 235, 33, 180, 238, 29, 61, 250, 38, 86, 120, 38, 49, 141, 17, 190, 191, 107, 95, 223, 222, 162, 116, 153, 232, 85, 100, 97, 41, 61, 219, 233, 237, 55, 246, 181]
>>> l[:100]
[28, 172, 79, 126, 36, 99, 103, 191, 146, 225, 24, 48, 113, 187, 48, 185, 31, 142, 216, 187, 27, 146, 215, 61, 111, 218, 171, 4, 160, 250, 110, 51, 128, 106, 3, 10, 116, 123, 128, 31, 73, 152, 58, 49, 184, 223, 17, 176, 166, 195, 6, 35, 206, 206, 39, 231, 89, 249, 21, 112, 168, 4, 88, 169, 215, 132, 255, 168, 129, 127, 60, 252, 244, 160, 80, 155, 246, 147, 234, 227, 157, 137, 101, 84, 115, 103, 77, 44, 84, 134, 140, 77, 224, 176, 242, 254, 171, 115, 193, 29]
```

#### Don't iterate by lines for binary files

Don't do the following - this pulls a chunk of arbitrary size until it gets to a newline character - too slow when the chunks are too small, and possibly too large as well:

```
    with open(path, 'rb') as file:
        for chunk in file: # text newline iteration - not for bytes
            yield from chunk
```

The above is only good for what are semantically human readable text files (like plain text, code, markup, markdown etc... essentially anything ascii, utf, latin, etc... encoded) that you should open without the `'b'` flag.

Comment: This is SO much better... thank you for doing this. I know it's not always fun to go back to a two year old answer, but I appreciate that you did it. I particularly like the "Don't iterate by lines" subheading :-)

Comment: Hi Aaron, is there any reason why you chose to use `path = Path(path),
    with path.open('rb') as file:` rather than use the built-in open function instead? They both do the same thing correct?

Comment: @JoshuaYonathan I use the `Path` object because it's a very convenient new way to handle  paths. Instead of passing around a string into the carefully chosen "right" functions, we can simply call the methods on the path object, which essentially contains most of the important functionality you want with what is semantically a path string. With IDEs that can inspect, we can more easily get autocompletion as well. We could accomplish the same with the `open` builtin, but there are lots of upsides when writing the program for the programmer to use the `Path` object instead.

Comment: The last method you mentioned using the function, `file_byte_iterator` is much faster than all methods I have tried on this page. Kudos to you!

Comment: @RickM: You might be interested in the [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013806/355230) I just posted.

Answer (score 42):

To read a file — one byte at a time (ignoring the buffering)  — you could use the [two-argument `iter(callable, sentinel)` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    for byte in iter(lambda: file.read(1), b''):
        # Do stuff with byte
```

It calls `file.read(1)` until it returns nothing `b''` (empty bytestring).  The memory doesn't grow unlimited for large files. You could pass `buffering=0`  to `open()`, to disable the buffering — it guarantees that only one byte is read per iteration (slow).

`with`-statement closes the file automatically — including the case when the code underneath raises an exception.

Despite the presence of internal buffering by default, it is still inefficient to process one byte at a time. For example, here's the `blackhole.py` utility that eats everything it is given:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Discard all input. `cat > /dev/null` analog."""
import sys
from functools import partial
from collections import deque

chunksize = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else (1 << 15)
deque(iter(partial(sys.stdin.detach().read, chunksize), b''), maxlen=0)
```

Example:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1000 | python3 blackhole.py
```

It processes *~1.5 GB/s* when `chunksize == 32768` on my machine and only *~7.5 MB/s* when `chunksize == 1`. That is, it is 200 times slower to read one byte at a time. Take it into account if you can rewrite your processing to use more than one byte at a time and *if* you need performance.

[`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) allows you to treat a file as a [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) and a file object simultaneously. It can serve as an alternative to loading the whole file in memory if you need access both interfaces. In particular, you can iterate one byte at a time over a memory-mapped file just using a plain `for`-loop:

```
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap

with open(filename, 'rb', 0) as f, mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ) as s:
    for byte in s: # length is equal to the current file size
        # Do stuff with byte
```

`mmap` supports the slice notation. For example, `mm[i:i+len]` returns `len` bytes from the file starting at position `i`. The context manager protocol is not supported before Python 3.2; you need to call `mm.close()` explicitly in this case. Iterating over each byte using `mmap` consumes more memory than `file.read(1)`, but `mmap` is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: I found the last example very interesting. Too bad there's no equivalent `numpy` memory-mapped (byte) arrays.

Comment: @martineau there is `numpy.memmap()` and you can get the data one byte at a time (ctypes.data). You could think of numpy arrays as just a little more than blobs in memory + metadata.

Comment: jfs: Thanks, excellent news! Didn't know such a thing it existed. Great answer, BTW.

Answer (score 22):

To sum up all the brilliant points of chrispy, Skurmedel, Ben Hoyt and Peter Hansen, this would be the optimal solution for processing a binary file one byte at a time:

```
with open("myfile", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        byte = f.read(1)
        if not byte:
            break
        do_stuff_with(ord(byte))
```

For python versions 2.6 and above, because:

- python buffers internally - no need to read chunks
- DRY principle - do not repeat the read line
- with statement ensures a clean file close
- 'byte' evaluates to false when there are no more bytes (not when a byte is zero)

Or use J. F. Sebastians solution for improved speed

```
from functools import partial

with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    for byte in iter(partial(file.read, 1), b''):
        # Do stuff with byte
```

Or if you want it as a generator function like demonstrated by codeape:

```
def bytes_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            byte = f.read(1)
            if not byte:
                break
            yield(ord(byte))

# example:
for b in bytes_from_file('filename'):
    do_stuff_with(b)
```

Comment: As the linked answer says, reading/processing one byte at a time is still slow in Python even if the reads are buffered. The performance can be improved drastically if several bytes at a time could be processed as in the example in the linked answer: 1.5GB/s vs. 7.5MB/s.

Answer (score 19):

This post itself is not a direct answer to the question. What it is instead is a data-driven extensible benchmark that can be used to compare many of the answers (and variations of utilizing new features added in later, more modern, versions of Python) that have been posted to this question — and should therefore be helpful in determining which has the best performance.

In a few cases I've modified the code in the referenced answer to make it compatible with the benchmark framework.

First, here are the results for what currently are the latest versions of Python 2 & 3:

```
Fastest to slowest execution speeds with 32-bit Python 2.7.16
  numpy version 1.16.5
  Test file size: 1,024 KiB
  100 executions, best of 3 repetitions

1                  Tcll (array.array) :   3.8943 secs, rel speed   1.00x,   0.00% slower (262.95 KiB/sec)
2  Vinay Sajip (read all into memory) :   4.1164 secs, rel speed   1.06x,   5.71% slower (248.76 KiB/sec)
3            codeape + iter + partial :   4.1616 secs, rel speed   1.07x,   6.87% slower (246.06 KiB/sec)
4                             codeape :   4.1889 secs, rel speed   1.08x,   7.57% slower (244.46 KiB/sec)
5               Vinay Sajip (chunked) :   4.1977 secs, rel speed   1.08x,   7.79% slower (243.94 KiB/sec)
6           Aaron Hall (Py 2 version) :   4.2417 secs, rel speed   1.09x,   8.92% slower (241.41 KiB/sec)
7                     gerrit (struct) :   4.2561 secs, rel speed   1.09x,   9.29% slower (240.59 KiB/sec)
8                     Rick M. (numpy) :   8.1398 secs, rel speed   2.09x, 109.02% slower (125.80 KiB/sec)
9                           Skurmedel :  31.3264 secs, rel speed   8.04x, 704.42% slower ( 32.69 KiB/sec)

Benchmark runtime (min:sec) - 03:26
```

---

```
Fastest to slowest execution speeds with 32-bit Python 3.8.0
  numpy version 1.17.4
  Test file size: 1,024 KiB
  100 executions, best of 3 repetitions

1  Vinay Sajip + "yield from" + "walrus operator" :   3.5235 secs, rel speed   1.00x,   0.00% slower (290.62 KiB/sec)
2                       Aaron Hall + "yield from" :   3.5284 secs, rel speed   1.00x,   0.14% slower (290.22 KiB/sec)
3         codeape + iter + partial + "yield from" :   3.5303 secs, rel speed   1.00x,   0.19% slower (290.06 KiB/sec)
4                      Vinay Sajip + "yield from" :   3.5312 secs, rel speed   1.00x,   0.22% slower (289.99 KiB/sec)
5      codeape + "yield from" + "walrus operator" :   3.5370 secs, rel speed   1.00x,   0.38% slower (289.51 KiB/sec)
6                          codeape + "yield from" :   3.5390 secs, rel speed   1.00x,   0.44% slower (289.35 KiB/sec)
7                                      jfs (mmap) :   4.0612 secs, rel speed   1.15x,  15.26% slower (252.14 KiB/sec)
8              Vinay Sajip (read all into memory) :   4.5948 secs, rel speed   1.30x,  30.40% slower (222.86 KiB/sec)
9                        codeape + iter + partial :   4.5994 secs, rel speed   1.31x,  30.54% slower (222.64 KiB/sec)
10                                        codeape :   4.5995 secs, rel speed   1.31x,  30.54% slower (222.63 KiB/sec)
11                          Vinay Sajip (chunked) :   4.6110 secs, rel speed   1.31x,  30.87% slower (222.08 KiB/sec)
12                      Aaron Hall (Py 2 version) :   4.6292 secs, rel speed   1.31x,  31.38% slower (221.20 KiB/sec)
13                             Tcll (array.array) :   4.8627 secs, rel speed   1.38x,  38.01% slower (210.58 KiB/sec)
14                                gerrit (struct) :   5.0816 secs, rel speed   1.44x,  44.22% slower (201.51 KiB/sec)
15                 Rick M. (numpy) + "yield from" :  11.8084 secs, rel speed   3.35x, 235.13% slower ( 86.72 KiB/sec)
16                                      Skurmedel :  11.8806 secs, rel speed   3.37x, 237.18% slower ( 86.19 KiB/sec)
17                                Rick M. (numpy) :  13.3860 secs, rel speed   3.80x, 279.91% slower ( 76.50 KiB/sec)

Benchmark runtime (min:sec) - 04:47
```

I also ran it with a much larger 10 MiB test file (which took nearly an hour to run) and got performance results which were comparable to those shown above.

Here's the code used to do the benchmarking:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import array
import atexit
from collections import deque, namedtuple
import io
from mmap import ACCESS_READ, mmap
import numpy as np
from operator import attrgetter
import os
import random
import struct
import sys
import tempfile
from textwrap import dedent
import time
import timeit
import traceback

try:
    xrange
except NameError:  # Python 3
    xrange = range


class KiB(int):
    """ KibiBytes - multiples of the byte units for quantities of information. """
    def __new__(self, value=0):
        return 1024*value


BIG_TEST_FILE = 1  # MiBs or 0 for a small file.
SML_TEST_FILE = KiB(64)
EXECUTIONS = 100  # Number of times each "algorithm" is executed per timing run.
TIMINGS = 3  # Number of timing runs.
CHUNK_SIZE = KiB(8)
if BIG_TEST_FILE:
    FILE_SIZE = KiB(1024) * BIG_TEST_FILE
else:
    FILE_SIZE = SML_TEST_FILE  # For quicker testing.

# Common setup for all algorithms -- prefixed to each algorithm's setup.
COMMON_SETUP = dedent("""
    # Make accessible in algorithms.
    from __main__ import array, deque, get_buffer_size, mmap, np, struct
    from __main__ import ACCESS_READ, CHUNK_SIZE, FILE_SIZE, TEMP_FILENAME
    from functools import partial
    try:
        xrange
    except NameError:  # Python 3
        xrange = range
""")


def get_buffer_size(path):
    """ Determine optimal buffer size for reading files. """
    st = os.stat(path)
    try:
        bufsize = st.st_blksize # Available on some Unix systems (like Linux)
    except AttributeError:
        bufsize = io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
    return bufsize

# Utility primarily for use when embedding additional algorithms into benchmark.
VERIFY_NUM_READ = """
    # Verify generator reads correct number of bytes (assumes values are correct).
    bytes_read = sum(1 for _ in file_byte_iterator(TEMP_FILENAME))
    assert bytes_read == FILE_SIZE, \
           'Wrong number of bytes generated: got {:,} instead of {:,}'.format(
                bytes_read, FILE_SIZE)
"""

TIMING = namedtuple('TIMING', 'label, exec_time')

class Algorithm(namedtuple('CodeFragments', 'setup, test')):

    # Default timeit "stmt" code fragment.
    _TEST = """
        #for b in file_byte_iterator(TEMP_FILENAME):  # Loop over every byte.
        #    pass  # Do stuff with byte...
        deque(file_byte_iterator(TEMP_FILENAME), maxlen=0)  # Data sink.
    """

    # Must overload __new__ because (named)tuples are immutable.
    def __new__(cls, setup, test=None):
        """ Dedent (unindent) code fragment string arguments.
        Args:
          `setup` -- Code fragment that defines things used by `test` code.
                     In this case it should define a generator function named
                     `file_byte_iterator()` that will be passed that name of a test file
                     of binary data. This code is not timed.
          `test` -- Code fragment that uses things defined in `setup` code.
                    Defaults to _TEST. This is the code that's timed.
        """
        test =  cls._TEST if test is None else test  # Use default unless one is provided.

        # Uncomment to replace all performance tests with one that verifies the correct
        # number of bytes values are being generated by the file_byte_iterator function.
        #test = VERIFY_NUM_READ

        return tuple.__new__(cls, (dedent(setup), dedent(test)))


algorithms = {

    'Aaron Hall (Py 2 version)': Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(path):
            with open(path, "rb") as file:
                callable = partial(file.read, 1024)
                sentinel = bytes() # or b''
                for chunk in iter(callable, sentinel):
                    for byte in chunk:
                        yield byte
    """),

    "codeape": Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(filename, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                while True:
                    chunk = f.read(chunksize)
                    if chunk:
                        for b in chunk:
                            yield b
                    else:
                        break
    """),

    "codeape + iter + partial": Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(filename, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                for chunk in iter(partial(f.read, chunksize), b''):
                    for b in chunk:
                        yield b
    """),

    "gerrit (struct)": Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(filename):
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                fmt = '{}B'.format(FILE_SIZE)  # Reads entire file at once.
                for b in struct.unpack(fmt, f.read()):
                    yield b
    """),

    'Rick M. (numpy)': Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(filename):
            for byte in np.fromfile(filename, 'u1'):
                yield byte
    """),

    "Skurmedel": Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(filename):
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                byte = f.read(1)
                while byte:
                    yield byte
                    byte = f.read(1)
    """),

    "Tcll (array.array)": Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(filename):
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                arr = array.array('B')
                arr.fromfile(f, FILE_SIZE)  # Reads entire file at once.
                for b in arr:
                    yield b
    """),

    "Vinay Sajip (read all into memory)": Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(filename):
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                bytes_read = f.read()  # Reads entire file at once.
            for b in bytes_read:
                yield b
    """),

    "Vinay Sajip (chunked)": Algorithm("""
        def file_byte_iterator(filename, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                chunk = f.read(chunksize)
                while chunk:
                    for b in chunk:
                        yield b
                    chunk = f.read(chunksize)
    """),

}  # End algorithms

#
# Versions of algorithms that will only work in certain releases (or better) of Python.
#
if sys.version_info >= (3, 3):
    algorithms.update({

        'codeape + iter + partial + "yield from"': Algorithm("""
            def file_byte_iterator(filename, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    for chunk in iter(partial(f.read, chunksize), b''):
                        yield from chunk
        """),

        'codeape + "yield from"': Algorithm("""
            def file_byte_iterator(filename, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    while True:
                        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
                        if chunk:
                            yield from chunk
                        else:
                            break
        """),

        "jfs (mmap)": Algorithm("""
            def file_byte_iterator(filename):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f, \
                     mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=ACCESS_READ) as s:
                    yield from s
        """),

        'Rick M. (numpy) + "yield from"': Algorithm("""
            def file_byte_iterator(filename):
            #    data = np.fromfile(filename, 'u1')
                yield from np.fromfile(filename, 'u1')
        """),

        'Vinay Sajip + "yield from"': Algorithm("""
            def file_byte_iterator(filename, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    chunk = f.read(chunksize)
                    while chunk:
                        yield from chunk  # Added in Py 3.3
                        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
        """),

    })  # End Python 3.3 update.

if sys.version_info >= (3, 5):
    algorithms.update({

        'Aaron Hall + "yield from"': Algorithm("""
            from pathlib import Path

            def file_byte_iterator(path):
                ''' Given a path, return an iterator over the file
                    that lazily loads the file.
                '''
                path = Path(path)
                bufsize = get_buffer_size(path)

                with path.open('rb') as file:
                    reader = partial(file.read1, bufsize)
                    for chunk in iter(reader, bytes()):
                        yield from chunk
        """),

    })  # End Python 3.5 update.

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8, 0):
    algorithms.update({

        'Vinay Sajip + "yield from" + "walrus operator"': Algorithm("""
            def file_byte_iterator(filename, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    while chunk := f.read(chunksize):
                        yield from chunk  # Added in Py 3.3
        """),

        'codeape + "yield from" + "walrus operator"': Algorithm("""
            def file_byte_iterator(filename, chunksize=CHUNK_SIZE):
                with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                    while chunk := f.read(chunksize):
                        yield from chunk
        """),

    })  # End Python 3.8.0 update.update.


#### Main ####

def main():
    global TEMP_FILENAME

    def cleanup():
        """ Clean up after testing is completed. """
        try:
            os.remove(TEMP_FILENAME)  # Delete the temporary file.
        except Exception:
            pass

    atexit.register(cleanup)

    # Create a named temporary binary file of pseudo-random bytes for testing.
    fd, TEMP_FILENAME = tempfile.mkstemp('.bin')
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'wb') as file:
         os.write(fd, bytearray(random.randrange(256) for _ in range(FILE_SIZE)))

    # Execute and time each algorithm, gather results.
    start_time = time.time()  # To determine how long testing itself takes.

    timings = []
    for label in algorithms:
        try:
            timing = TIMING(label,
                            min(timeit.repeat(algorithms[label].test,
                                              setup=COMMON_SETUP + algorithms[label].setup,
                                              repeat=TIMINGS, number=EXECUTIONS)))
        except Exception as exc:
            print('{} occurred timing the algorithm: "{}"\n  {}'.format(
                    type(exc).__name__, label, exc))
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)  # Redirect to stdout.
            sys.exit(1)
        timings.append(timing)

    # Report results.
    print('Fastest to slowest execution speeds with {}-bit Python {}.{}.{}'.format(
            64 if sys.maxsize > 2**32 else 32, *sys.version_info[:3]))
    print('  numpy version {}'.format(np.version.full_version))
    print('  Test file size: {:,} KiB'.format(FILE_SIZE // KiB(1)))
    print('  {:,d} executions, best of {:d} repetitions'.format(EXECUTIONS, TIMINGS))
    print()

    longest = max(len(timing.label) for timing in timings)  # Len of longest identifier.
    ranked = sorted(timings, key=attrgetter('exec_time')) # Sort so fastest is first.
    fastest = ranked[0].exec_time
    for rank, timing in enumerate(ranked, 1):
        print('{:<2d} {:>{width}} : {:8.4f} secs, rel speed {:6.2f}x, {:6.2f}% slower '
              '({:6.2f} KiB/sec)'.format(
                    rank,
                    timing.label, timing.exec_time, round(timing.exec_time/fastest, 2),
                    round((timing.exec_time/fastest - 1) * 100, 2),
                    (FILE_SIZE/timing.exec_time) / KiB(1),  # per sec.
                    width=longest))
    print()
    mins, secs = divmod(time.time()-start_time, 60)
    print('Benchmark runtime (min:sec) - {:02d}:{:02d}'.format(int(mins),
                                                               int(round(secs))))

main()
```

Comment: Are you assuming I do `yield from chunk` instead `for byte in chunk: yield byte`? I'm thinking I should tighten up my answer with that.

Comment: @Aaron: There are two versions your answer in the Python 3 results and one of them uses `yield from`.

Comment: ok, I've updated my answer. also I suggest you drop `enumerate` as the iteration should be understood to complete - if not, last I checked - enumerate has a bit of overhead with costs over doing the bookkeeping for the index with += 1, so you might alternatively do the bookkeeping in your own code. Or even pass to a deque with `maxlen=0`.

Comment: @Aaron: Agree about the `enumerate`. Thanks for the feedback. Will be adding an update to my post that doesn't have it (although I don't think it changes the results much). Will also be adding @Rick M.'s `numpy`-based answer.

Comment: A bit more code review: I don't think it makes any sense to write answers to Python 2 at this point - I'd consider removing Python 2 as I would expect you to use 64 bit Python 3.7 or 3.8. You could set the cleanup to go at the end with atexit and a partial application. Typo: "veriify". I see no sense in the duplication of the test strings - are they at all different? I imagine if you use `super().` instead of `tuple.` in your `__new__` you could use the `namedtuple` attribute names instead of indexes.

Comment: @Aaron: Will take your advice under consideration. The Python 2 stuff is there mainly for historical reasons, the question's over ten years old (and I don't think it's all that distracting). Most of your other ideas sound interesting and I'll play around with them for my own enlightenment — but frankly optimizing the benchmark isn't a high priority. It's serving its raison d'être as far as I'm concerned — although I'm always up for learning how to improve code and make it more reusable. At any rate, thanks for the constructive criticism.

Comment: @Aaron: I fixed a bug in the calculation of MiBs per second file processing speed — was making it higher than it actually was — but in the end it didn't change the results much because they're all relative (although I noticed your answer seemed to fair better for some reason). Also reorganized the code to make it more PEP 8 compliant and incorporated several of your suggestions while I was at it.

Answer (score 7):

Python 3, read all of the file at once:

```
with open("filename", "rb") as binary_file:
    # Read the whole file at once
    data = binary_file.read()
    print(data)
```

You can iterate whatever you want using `data` variable.

Answer (score 6):

After trying all the above and using the answer from @Aaron Hall, I was getting memory errors for a ~90 Mb file on a computer running Window 10, 8 Gb RAM and Python 3.5 32-bit. I was recommended by a colleague to use `numpy` instead and it works wonders.

By far, the fastest to read an entire binary file (that I have tested) is:

```
import numpy as np

file = "binary_file.bin"
data = np.fromfile(file, 'u1')
```

[Reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html)

Multitudes faster than any other methods so far. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: @Nirmal: The question is about looping over reach byte, so it's not clear if your comment about different data types has any bearing.

Comment: Rick: Your code isn't doing quite the same thing as the others — namely looping over each byte. If that's added to it, it isn't any faster than the majority of the others according at least according to the results in my [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013806/355230). In fact it appears to be one of the slower approaches. If the processing done to each byte (whatever that might be) was something that could be done via `numpy`, then might be worthwhile.

Comment: @martineau Thanks for your comments, yes I do understand that the question is about looping over each byte and not just loading everything in one go, but there are other answers in this question which also point to reading all contents and hence my answer

Comment: @Nirmal  You're also wrong. numpy from file can read different types using dtypes: 
===================================

dtheader= np.dtype([('Start Name','b', (4,)),
                ('Message Type', np.int32, (1,)),
                ('Instance', np.int32, (1,)),
                ('NumItems', np.int32, (1,)),
                ('Length', np.int32, (1,)),
                ('ComplexArray', np.int32, (1,))])
dtheader=dtheader.newbyteorder('>')

headerinfo = np.fromfile(iqfile, dtype=dtheader, count=1)

Comment: @KurtPeters Oh, I didn't know that you could pass a custom dtype. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of binary data to read, you might want to consider the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).  It is documented as converting "between C and Python types", but of course, bytes are bytes, and whether those were created as C types does not matter.  For example, if your binary data contains two 2-byte integers and one 4-byte integer, you can read them as follows (example taken from `struct` documentation):

```
>>> struct.unpack('hhl', b'\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03')
(1, 2, 3)
```

You might find this more convenient, faster, or both, than explicitly looping over the content of a file.

Answer (score 4):

if you are looking for something speedy, here's a method I've been using that's worked for years:

```
from array import array

with open( path, 'rb' ) as file:
    data = array( 'B', file.read() ) # buffer the file

# evaluate it's data
for byte in data:
    v = byte # int value
    c = chr(byte)
```

if you want to iterate chars instead of ints, you can simply use `data = file.read()`, which should be a bytes() object in py3.

Comment: 'array' is imported by 'from array import array'

Comment: @quanly_mc yes, thanks for catching that, and sorry I forgot to include that, editing now.

Answer (score 2):

for large size I think using a generator wont be bad, this answer is for reading something like a file, though @codeapp has a similar answer i think removing the inner loop will make more sense.

```
def read_chunk(file_object, chunk_size=125):
    while True:
        file =  file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not file:
            break
        yield file


#sample use 
buffer = io.BytesIO()
file = open('myfile', 'r')
for chunk in read_chunk(file):
    buffer.write(chunk)
buffer.seek(0)
// save the file or do whatever you want here
```

you can still use it as a normal list, i dont think this is of any use but

```
file_list = list(read_chunk(file, chunk_size=10000))
for i in file_list:
    # do something
```

and also get the index of each chunk

```
for index, chunk in enumurate(read_chunk(file, chunk_size=10000)):
    #use the index as a number index
    # you can try and get the size of each chunk with this 
    length = len(chunk)
```

##### mind you, pay attention to the size of the file, and the chunk_size is always in bytes at note.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of reading Network endian data using Numpy fromfile addressing @Nirmal comments above:

```
dtheader= np.dtype([('Start Name','b', (4,)),
                ('Message Type', np.int32, (1,)),
                ('Instance', np.int32, (1,)),
                ('NumItems', np.int32, (1,)),
                ('Length', np.int32, (1,)),
                ('ComplexArray', np.int32, (1,))])
dtheader=dtheader.newbyteorder('>')

headerinfo = np.fromfile(iqfile, dtype=dtheader, count=1)

print(raw['Start Name'])
```

I hope this helps. The problem is that fromfile doesn't recognize and EOF and allow gracefully breaking out of the loop for files of arbitrary size.