# Python - Opening and changing large text files

Tags: python, replace, out-of-memory, large-files

I have a ~600MB Roblox type .mesh file, which reads like a text file in any text editor. I have the following code below:

```
mesh = open("file.mesh", "r").read()
mesh = mesh.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}").replace("}{", "},{")
mesh = "{"+mesh+"}"
f = open("p2t.txt", "w")
f.write(mesh)
```

It returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TheDirectoryToMyFile\p2t2.py", line 2, in <module>
    mesh = mesh.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}").replace("}{", "},{")
MemoryError
```

Here is a sample of my file:

```
[-0.00599, 0.001466, 0.006][0.16903, 0.84515, 0.50709][0.00000, 0.00000, 0][-0.00598, 0.001472, 0.00599][0.09943, 0.79220, 0.60211][0.00000, 0.00000, 0]
```

What can I do?

Edit:

I'm not sure what the head, follow, and tail commands are in that other thread that marked this as a duplicate. I tried to use it, but couldn't get it to work. The file is also one giant line, it isn't split into lines.

Comment: try doing the replace's one at a time.  Try reading some Tutorials.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read large text files in Python, line by line without loading it in to memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory)

Comment: It may not be a duplicate if the file has no lines. @GShocked Is the file split into lines?

Comment: Case you change order to replace to mesh.replace('][','},{').replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}") it will be done faster

Comment: @jamylak No, it is all in one line

Comment: If the file is all one line, I am **extremely** doubtful that it "reads like a text file in any text editor". Most text editors I've seen will process files extremely slowly when they have very long lines, and use many times as much memory as the size of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read one bite per iteration, analyze it and then write to another file or to `sys.stdout`. Try this code:

```
mesh = open("file.mesh", "r")
mesh_out = open("file-1.mesh", "w")

c = mesh.read(1)

if c:
    mesh_out.write("{")
else:
    exit(0)
while True:
    c = mesh.read(1)
    if c == "":
        break

    if c == "[":
        mesh_out.write(",{")
    elif c == "]":
        mesh_out.write("}")
    else:
        mesh_out.write©
```

UPD:

It works really slow (thanks to jamylak). So I've changed it:

```
import sys
import re


def process_char(c, stream, is_first=False):
    if c == '':
        return False
    if c == '[':
        stream.write('{' if is_first else ',{')
        return True
    if c == ']':
        stream.write('}')
        return True


def process_file(fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as mesh:
        c = mesh.read(1)
        if c == '':
            return
        sys.stdout.write('{')

        while True:
            c = mesh.read(8192)
            if c == '':
                return

            c = re.sub(r'\[', ',{', c)
            c = re.sub(r'\]', '}', c)
            sys.stdout.write(c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_file(sys.argv[1])
```

So now it's working ~15 sec on 1.4G file. To run it:

```
$ python mesh.py file.mesh > file-1.mesh
```

Comment: nice. see also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872381/how-to-read-a-file-byte-by-byte-in-python-and-how-to-print-a-bytelist-as-a-binar

Comment: Might be a good idea to work *within* a context manager using a ```with``` statement. ```mesh_out``` should be opened for *appending*

Comment: Reading `1` byte at a time is super slow though. You should use a buffer size of eg. default `8192` and run `.replace()` on each chunk

Comment: I'm wondering how you handle the case of `},{` however. Its not too hard will just make things more complicated similar to how this answer deals with newlines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python

Comment: I will try this now, it hasn't completed yet though. The second `elif` is missing a `:`, but I fixed that.

Comment: @GShocked I would recommend you change `.read(1)` to `.read(8192)` or adjusted. And change the `if` statements to 2 `.replace`s and it will complete faster. (and then also fix anything else in code if necessary)

Comment: @jamylak I'll try that, but it is more than half done so I will wait a bit to do that.

Comment: I need to change the file because I just realized that the output is too large for Roblox. I will make the mesh smaller. This script partly worked. It didn't surround the entire thing with another pair of curly braces though.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it line by line:

```
mesh = open("file.mesh", "r")
with open("p2t.txt", "w") as f:
   for line in mesh:
      line= line.replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}").replace("}{", "},{")
      line = "{"+line +"}"
      f.write(line)
```

Comment: Still a memory error, maybe I need more ram? I have 8GB but one of my sticks failed and I only have 4GB now

Comment: try it now, this should iterate through lines

Comment: oh there are no newline characters in the file that's why this isn't working

Comment: @maxymoo Yes it's better now, but I would either move `open("file.mesh", "r")` into the `with` (preferred) or at least call `.close()` on it

Answer (score 2):

```
BLOCK_SIZE = 1 << 15
with open(input_file, 'rb') as fin, open(output_file, 'wb') as fout:
    for block in iter(lambda: fin.read(BLOCK_SIZE), b''):
        # do your replace
        fout.write(block)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
f = open('p2f.txt','w')
with open("file.mesh") as mesh:
  while True:
    c = mesh.read(1)
    if not c:
      f.seek(-1,os.SEEK_END)
      f.truncate()
      break
    elif c == '[':
        f.write('{')
    elif c == ']':
        f.write('},')
   else:
       f.write(c)
```

`p2f.txt`:

```
{-0.00599, 0.001466, 0.006},{0.16903, 0.84515, 0.50709},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0},{-0.00598, 0.001472, 0.00599},{0.09943, 0.79220, 0.60211},{0.00000, 0.00000, 0}
```

Comment: Reading by `1` byte at a time is super slow as I said before. You should read by a larger buffer size. If you don't believe me look up what Linus torvalds said about it

Comment: @jamylak I agree, but I was trying to avoid MemoryError :)

Comment: No that's wrong, the memory is capable of holding more than `1` byte at a time.

Comment: @jamylak , yes I do know we can read a chunk of file at once :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def read(afilename):
    with open("afilename", "r") as file
       lines = file.readlines()
       lines.replace("[", "{")
       #place reset of code here in
```

Comment: that would depend on the size of the file being read/written ??. on a small file, could you say you would notice it ?

Comment: On a small file you would not notice. but the question is  specifically about "opening large files" and says "600mb file". Also its bad practice to use `.readlines()`, i never use it