# Why can I not read more than 16 bytes of a JPEG file in Python?

Tags: python, image, byte, jpeg

I am trying to read a JPG image in Python.

So far i have:

```
f = open("test.jpg")
ima = f.read(16)

print "'%s'"% (ima)
```

It reads 16 bytes and displays the string in console, but it looks like I cannot display more than 32 bytes. Why?

When it tries to read 32 or more bytes, the output will be the same as when it read 16 bytes. Why can I not read more than 16 bytes of the jpeg image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. Set read mode to binary. This way `file.read` function won't try to convert '\r\n' sequences.
2. You're trying to print NULL-terminated string to the console. `print` function finds first zero character in your string and terminates. Use `binascii.hexlify` to convert it to the hex:

```
f = open("test.jpg", "rb")
ima = f.read(16)

print "%s" % (binascii.hexlify(ima))
```

Comment: Rather than that *horribly* named function in binascii, `repr()` might be more useful here.

Comment: @yurymik does the `(16)` argument mean it reads in 16 bytes, or that it reads it in units of 16 bits?

Comment: @joshsvoss:
file.read([size])
Read at most size bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: use f.read() to read the complete file , no need  to find the size of the file or loop over f.readline() to see the output of everyline

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to set the open mode to binary:

```
f = open("test.jpg", "rb") # 'rb' here means "read mode, binary"
```

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python) for a more thorough description.