# Lua script poroblem with reade file (encrypted ?)

Tags: encryption, lua

I try modify project wrote in LUA script. But i dn't know why i can't read it.
It looks like encripted. It is possible to read this file ?
here is file
https://easyupload.io/c3u934

[screen from file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyO6I.png)

i used unluac but i it doesnt work. below is my example:

> java -jar unluac.jar options.lua > myfile_decompiled.lua

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The input file does not have the signature of a valid Lua file.
        at unluac.parse.BHeader.<init>(BHeader.java:70)
        at unluac.Main.file_to_function(Main.java:116)
        at unluac.Main.main(Main.java:58)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's encrypted and not just compiled? Does [unluac](https://github.com/HansWessels/unluac) understand it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post.

Comment: What program does this script run in? How exactly does it get loaded?

Comment: If you can't share the actual file (a screenshot isn't good enough) and can't give us more details about the context of this, such as what program it runs inside of, then there's nothing that can be done.

Comment: You're still missing necessary context. What program is capable of running this file?

Comment: these files, but after commpiling https://github.com/edubart/otclient/tree/master/modules/client_entergame

Comment: Are you sure it was actually the client as-is from that repo, and not a modified one as explained at https://otland.net/threads/how-to-encrypt-client-files-just-tips-not-full-working-code.235838/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked at the file with a hex editor, I saw a lot of repeating patterns, which implied weak XOR encryption. Long strings of the `0x05` byte really made this seem likely, which I suspected were spaces (`0x20`) in the original Lua file. I XOR'd every byte of the file with `0x25` to test this theory, and it worked! Here's the result:

```
EnterGame = { }

-- private variables
local loadBox
local enterGame
local motdWindow
clientBox = nil
local protocolLogin
local motdEnabled = true
local progressWindow
local startTime
-- private functions
local function onError(protocol, message, errorCode)
  if loadBox then
    loadBox:destroy()
    loadBox = nil
  end

  if enterGame:getChildById('rememberPasswordBox'):isChecked() then

        --local account = g_crypt.xorCrypt(G.account, 123)
    --local password = g_crypt.xorCrypt(G.password, 123)

        local account = g_crypt.encrypt(G.account)
    local password = g_crypt.encrypt(G.password)

    if account ~= "" and password ~= "" then
      g_settings.set('account', account)
      g_settings.set('password', password)
      ServerList.setServerAccount(G.host, account)
      ServerList.setServerPassword(G.host, password)
        end
  else
    -- reset server list account/password
    ServerList.setServerAccount(G.host, '')
    ServerList.setServerPassword(G.host, '')
    EnterGame.clearAccountFields()
  end

  local errorBox = displayErrorBox(tr('Login Error'), message)
  connect(errorBox, { onOk = EnterGame.show })
end

local function onMotd(protocol, motd)
  G.motdNumber = tonumber(motd:sub(0, motd:find("\n")))
  G.motdMessage = motd:sub(motd:find("\n") + 1, #motd)
  if motdEnabled then
  end
end

local function onCharacterList(protocol, characters, account, otui)
  -- Try add server to the server list
  ServerList.add(G.host, G.port, g_game.getClientVersion())

  if enterGame:getChildById('rememberPasswordBox'):isChecked() then

    local account = g_crypt.encrypt(G.account)
    local password = g_crypt.encrypt(G.password)

        --local account = g_crypt.xorCrypt(G.account, 123)
    --local password = g_crypt.xorCrypt(G.password, 123)

    if account ~= "" and  password ~= "" then
      g_settings.set('account', account)
      g_settings.set('password', password)
      ServerList.setServerAccount(G.host, account)
      ServerList.setServerPassword(G.host, password)
        end
  else
    -- reset server list account/password
    ServerList.setServerAccount(G.host, '')
    ServerList.setServerPassword(G.host, '')
    EnterGame.clearAccountFields()
  end

  loadBox:destroy()
  loadBox = nil

  CharacterList.create(characters, account, otui)
  CharacterList.show()

  if motdEnabled then
    local lastMotdNumber = g_settings.getNumber("motd")
    if G.motdNumber and G.motdNumber ~= lastMotdNumber then
      g_settings.set("motd", G.motdNumber)
      motdWindow = displayInfoBox(tr('Message of the day'), G.motdMessage)
      connect(motdWindow, { onOk = function() CharacterList.show() motdWindow = nil end })
      CharacterList.hide()
    end
  end
end

-- public functions
function EnterGame.init()
  connect(g_app, { onExit = onExitFunc })
  enterGame = g_ui.displayUI('entergame')

  g_keyboard.bindKeyDown('Ctrl+G', EnterGame.openWindow)

  local account = g_settings.get('account')
  local password = g_settings.get('password')
  local host = g_settings.get('host')
  local port = g_settings.get('port')
  local clientVersion = g_settings.getInteger('client-version')
  local proxy = g_settings.get('proxy')
  if clientVersion == 0 then clientVersion = 772 end
  if port == nil or port == 0 then port = 7181 end

  if account ~= "" then
     EnterGame.setAccountName(account)
  end
  if password ~= "" then
     EnterGame.setPassword(password)
  end

  enterGame:getChildById('serverHostTextEdit'):setText(host)
  enterGame:getChildById('serverPortTextEdit'):setText(port)
  clientBox = enterGame:getChildById('clientComboBox')

  clientBox:addOption("Prosperity")
  clientBox:addOption("Encounter")
  clientBox:addOption("Redemption")
  clientBox:addOption("War")
  --clientBox:addOption("test")
  clientBox:setCurrentOption(proxy)
  clientBox.menuHeight = 97
  --clientBox:hide()
  enterGame:hide()

  if g_app.isRunning() and not g_game.isOnline() then
    enterGame:show()
  end
end

function EnterGame.terminate()
  disconnect(g_app, { onExit = onExitFunc })

  g_keyboard.unbindKeyDown('Ctrl+G')
  enterGame:destroy()
  enterGame = nil
  clientBox = nil
  if motdWindow then
    motdWindow:destroy()
    motdWindow = nil
  end
  if loadBox then
    loadBox:destroy()
    loadBox = nil
  end
  if protocolLogin then
    protocolLogin:cancelLogin()
    protocolLogin = nil
  end
  cancelDownload()
  EnterGame = nil
end

function EnterGame.show()
if modules.client.startBox or modules.client.failDownloadBox or modules.client.finishBox or modules.client.failCheckBox then return false end
if modules.client.updateBox and modules.client.updateBox:isVisible() then return false end

if g_game.isLogging() or CharacterList.isVisible() then return false end
  if loadBox or progressWindow then return end
  enterGame:show()
  enterGame:raise()
  enterGame:focus()
end

function EnterGame.hide()
  enterGame:hide()
end

function EnterGame.openWindow()
  if g_game.isOnline() then
    CharacterList.show()
  elseif not g_game.isLogging() and not CharacterList.isVisible() then
    EnterGame.show()
  end
end

function EnterGame.setAccountName(account)
  local account = g_crypt.decrypt(account)
  --local account = g_crypt.xorCrypt(account, 123)
  enterGame:getChildById('accountNameTextEdit'):setText(account)
  enterGame:getChildById('accountNameTextEdit'):setCursorPos(-1)
  enterGame:getChildById('rememberPasswordBox'):setChecked(#account > 0)
end

function EnterGame.setPassword(password)
  local password = g_crypt.decrypt(password)
  --local password = g_crypt.xorCrypt(password, 123)
  enterGame:getChildById('accountPasswordTextEdit'):setText(password)
end

function EnterGame.clearAccountFields()
  local accountText = enterGame:getChildById('accountNameTextEdit')
  local passwordText = enterGame:getChildById('accountPasswordTextEdit')
  if accountText:getText() ~= "" then
     accountText:clearText()
  end
  if passwordText:getText() ~= "" then
     passwordText:clearText()
  end
  enterGame:getChildById('accountNameTextEdit'):focus()
  g_settings.remove('account')
  g_settings.remove('password')

end

function EnterGame.doLogin(cast, cams)
  G.account = enterGame:getChildById('accountNameTextEdit'):getText()
  G.password = enterGame:getChildById('accountPasswordTextEdit'):getText()
  G.host = enterGame:getChildById('serverHostTextEdit'):getText()
  G.port = tonumber(enterGame:getChildById('serverPortTextEdit'):getText())
  local clientVersion = tonumber("772")
  EnterGame.hide()

  if g_game.isOnline() then
    local errorBox = displayErrorBox(tr('Login Error'), tr('You are already logged in.'))
    connect(errorBox, { onOk = EnterGame.show })
    return
  end

  g_settings.set('host', G.host)
  g_settings.set('port', G.port)
  g_settings.set('client-version', clientVersion)
  g_settings.set('proxy', clientBox:getCurrentOption().text)

  protocolLogin = ProtocolLogin.create()
  protocolLogin.onLoginError = onError
  protocolLogin.onMotd = onMotd
  protocolLogin.onCharacterList = onCharacterList
  protocolLogin.onUpdateNeeded = onUpdateNeeded

  loadBox = displayCancelBox(tr('Please wait'), tr('Your character list is being loaded. Please wait.'))
  connect(loadBox, { onCancel = function(msgbox)
                                  loadBox = nil
                                  protocolLogin:cancelLogin()
                                  EnterGame.show()
                                end })

  g_game.setProtocolVersion(g_game.getClientProtocolVersion(clientVersion))
  g_game.chooseRsa(G.host)

  if modules.game_things.isLoaded() then

    if clientBox:getCurrentOption().text == "Redemption" then
       G.port = "7171"
        elseif clientBox:getCurrentOption().text == "Prosperity" then
           G.port = "7175"
    elseif clientBox:getCurrentOption().text == "War" then
           G.port = "7181"
    elseif clientBox:getCurrentOption().text == "test" then
           G.port = "7177"
    elseif clientBox:getCurrentOption().text == "Encounter" then
           G.port = "7185"
        end

    if cast then
           G.account = ""
        end

        if cams then
           G.account = ""
           G.port = 7194
        end

        protocolLogin:login(G.host, G.port, G.account, G.password)

  else
    loadBox:destroy()
    loadBox = nil
    EnterGame.show()
  end
end

function EnterGame.displayMotd()
  if not motdWindow then
    motdWindow = displayInfoBox(tr('Message of the day'), G.motdMessage)
    motdWindow.onOk = function() motdWindow = nil end
  end
end

function EnterGame.setDefaultServer(host, port, protocol)
  local hostTextEdit = enterGame:getChildById('serverHostTextEdit')
  local portTextEdit = enterGame:getChildById('serverPortTextEdit')
  local clientLabel = enterGame:getChildById('clientLabel')
  local accountTextEdit = enterGame:getChildById('accountNameTextEdit')
  local passwordTextEdit = enterGame:getChildById('accountPasswordTextEdit')

  if hostTextEdit:getText() ~= host then
    hostTextEdit:setText(host)
    portTextEdit:setText(port)
    accountTextEdit:setText('')
    passwordTextEdit:setText('')
  end
end

function EnterGame.setUniqueServer(host, port, protocol, windowWidth, windowHeight)
  local hostTextEdit = enterGame:getChildById('serverHostTextEdit')
  hostTextEdit:setText(host)
  hostTextEdit:setVisible(false)
  hostTextEdit:setHeight(0)
  local portTextEdit = enterGame:getChildById('serverPortTextEdit')
  portTextEdit:setText(port)
  portTextEdit:setVisible(false)
  portTextEdit:setHeight(0)

  local portLabel = enterGame:getChildById('portLabel')
  portLabel:setVisible(false)
  portLabel:setHeight(0)
  local clientLabel = enterGame:getChildById('clientLabel')
  clientLabel:setVisible(false)
  clientLabel:setHeight(0)

  local serverListButton = enterGame:getChildById('serverListButton')
  serverListButton:setVisible(false)
  serverListButton:setHeight(0)
  serverListButton:setWidth(0)

  local rememberPasswordBox = enterGame:getChildById('rememberPasswordBox')

  if not windowWidth then windowWidth = 240 end
  enterGame:setWidth(windowWidth)
  if not windowHeight then windowHeight = 230 end
  enterGame:setHeight(windowHeight)
end

function EnterGame.setServerInfo(message)
  local label = enterGame:getChildById('serverInfoLabel')
  label:setText(message)
end

function EnterGame.disableMotd()
  motdEnabled = false
end
```

Comment: thanks you ;), Cluld you please describe step by step how you do it ? please, i have about 20 files. It can very help me. please

Comment: @rrrrcode https://stackoverflow.com/a/5040002/7509065 has a quick-and-dirty Python script to do it. Just change `0x71` to `0x25`.

Comment: could you please explain to me how you saw lot of repeating patterns, i opened file with a hex editor and i don't see  repeating patterns. Cluld you please in more details why you Xord it by 0x25 ?

Comment: @rrrrcode Bytes `0x1cf8` through `0x1d19` are all `0x05`. On a hunch, I guessed that these were spaces, which are `0x20`, so I did `0x05` XOR `0x20` and got `0x25`, and then used that as the key to XOR the whole file with.

Comment: ok, i know now i have last question about repeating patterns i upload screen of my hex editor https://ibb.co/106Nf6f could you please look on it, and help me to find these patterns ?

Comment: @rrrrcode Why do you need to find the patterns yourself? I expect that all of the Lua files you got from this project will be XOR'd with the same key.

Comment: yes, but i would like to learn it, I like to know what I do :) and not to write posts again in the future

Comment: @rrrrcode Anyway, in the screenshot you posted, some good clues are the repeating strings `KQ@WbDh@` and `IJFDI`. The keyword `local` is really common in Lua, and XORing the bytes of `IJFDI` with `0x25` turns it into `local`.

Comment: do you recommend any other hex editor for it? it look like skipped spaces in my example

Comment: @rrrrcode The hex editor in your screenshot is fine and does not have "skipped spaces". It sounds like you're just not familiar with how hex editors work.