# How To Convert a File with ASCII Numbers 0 - 9 to base 8 HEX Using Linux?

Tags: hex, hexdump

I have found many topics that get me close to what I want to accomplish such as printf but out of a 1.7GB file I get a 12 byte output file.  lol

Such as -

```
printf '%x\n' $(< input.txt) > output.txt
```

I have a large file containing 8 digit numbers.

```
01234567
```

Hex values:   `0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37`

I really want:
Hex values:  `0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x04, 0x06, 0x07`

input file and output file

Thank you!

Comment: I think I answered my own question.

Comment: There are a couple of python scripts...
By tinkering around, I found XOR 0x30  will get the results I want, ...

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037762/xor-each-byte-with-0x71)

Changed the 0x71 to 0x30.

Also trying another script, 
[link](https://samsclass.info/124/proj14/VPxor.htm)

for k, the key, the last agrument, I entered 0 (which is 0x30) because I could not understand how to enter $'\x30' without an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of python scripts...
By tinkering around, I found XOR 0x30  will get the results I want, ...

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037762/xor-each-byte-with-0x71)

Changed the 0x71 to 0x30.

Also trying another script,
[link](https://samsclass.info/124/proj14/VPxor.htm)

for k, the key, the last agrument, I entered 0 (which is 0x30) because I could not understand how to enter $'\x30' without an error.