# Understanding Python struct.pack and binary input

Tags: python, scapy

The following function accepts a binary 4 byte key for `key`. `buf` is binary input which is xor'd against the 4 byte key.

```
def four_byte_xor(buf, key):
    #key = struct.pack(b">I", key) # removed for binary processing
    buf = bytearray(buf)
    for offset in range(0, len(buf), 4):
        for i, byte in enumerate(key):
            buf[offset + i] = chr(buf[offset + i] ^ ord(byte))
    return str(buf)
```

I removed `key = struct.pack(b">I", key)` from `four_byte_xor()` in order to specify binary data via `str(p.payload.payload.payload)[:4]` for `key`. This works fine if the length end in 4 bytes, otherwise the following error fires (see testing below).

Here are some tests consisting of an input xor'd with a key resulting in 00, first one being successful:

```
'ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD'
'ABCD'

bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
'ABCD'
```

Second test is not successful and end in A or 1 extra byte:

```
'ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDA'
'ABCD'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./decode.py", line 36, in <module>
    process_packets()
  File "./decode.py", line 34, in process_packets
    out_buf.write(bin_four_byte_xor(pkt_payload, pkt_offset))
  File "./decode.py", line 22, in bin_four_byte_xor
    buf[offset + i] = chr(buf[offset + i] ^ ord(byte))
IndexError: bytearray index out of range
```

Can the `four_byte_xor()` be modified to accept varying `buf` lengths?

Comment: Your errors with `linehexdump` were because that function doesn't return the hex values, but just prints them. I'm glad to see you've abandoned that approach. Using your binary data directly as the key makes much more sense. Is the `buff` bytearray an exact multiple of 4 in length? If not, you'll get an out of range error when you get to the extra 1-3 bytes at the end.

Comment: It may not be though I have tested individual packets and it seems to work fine. When I try feeding multiple packets through the buffer is when I receive the index out of range. Should their be something that clears the `buf` and `key` between iterations or is that automatic?

Comment: This question comes close to providing a [reproducible example](http://sscce.org/), but not quite. Before you mention what else you tried, can you include the *precise code that fails*, the *unshortened* (except when it comes to file names) error message, and the function call (i.e. something like `four_byte_xor(b'a', 42)`) so that the program becomes a self-contained example? If you don't know the exact arguments, you can use `print(repr(buf))` to display them in the live system.

Comment: It appears that there is some variance. Updated question with output from `print(repr(buf))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can modify the function to accept varying key lengths.  For example, something like

```
def many_byte_xor(buf, key):
    buf = bytearray(buf)
    for i, bufbyte in enumerate(buf):
        buf[i] = chr(bufbyte ^ ord(key[i % len(key)]))
    return str(buf)
```

which cycles over all the characters of the key (the modulus version of `itertools.cycle`).  This produces

```
>>> many_byte_xor("AABAA", "AB")
'\x00\x03\x03\x03\x00'
>>> many_byte_xor("ABCDABCD", "ABCD")
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> many_byte_xor("ABCDABCDA", "ABCD")
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> many_byte_xor("ABCDABCDAB", "ABCD")
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> many_byte_xor("ABCDABCDAB", "ABC")
'\x00\x00\x00\x05\x03\x01\x02\x06\x02\x03'
```

which IIUC is what you want.

Comment: For a little more efficiency, you could add a `key = bytearray(key)` and a `key_len = len(key)` just before the loop and then the assignment within it could be simplified to just `buf[i] = bufbyte ^ key[i % key_len]`. Because `bytearray`s are just mutable sequences of small integers, there's no need for the `ord()` and the `chr()` function calls.