# How to convert a 8-bit number to an actual byte in Python?

Tags: python

Say I have 8 bits

```
01010101
```

which equals the byte

```
u
```

But I what I actually have is 8 binaries(well, integers). How do I convert these 8 binaries to the corresponding byte?

I'm trying

```
byte = int(int('01010101'), 2)
byte = chr(byte)
byte = bytes(byte)
```

But this gives me a bytes array instead of a single byte...

Comment: What do you mean by "8 binaries"?  What is the type of the data?  There is no builtin type in Python for a single byte.  What do you want to do with that byte once you have it?

Comment: @BrenBarn The 8 binaries are integers. I want to write this byte I get to a binary file.

Comment: In your example, you seem to have a string containing 8 characters, not an integer.  If you want to write the byte to a binary file, you can do that just as well with a byte array of length 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of python are you on? I get the 85 and 'U' using the same statements as you did, using 2.7.8:

```
int('01010101', 2)
>>> 85
int(int('01010101', 2))  # not needed
>>> 85
chr(int('01010101', 2))
>>> 'U'
bytes(chr(int('01010101', 2)))  # not needed
>>> 'U'
```

To actually write the binary data to file, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18367068/1431750) (for py 2 and 3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20955678/1431750). File `mode` should be 'wb'. And don't convert to chr.

Comment: I got it. I forgot to convert the number from base 2 to base 10 at some point. Thank you @aneroid

Answer (score 2):

The following is interpreted as an octal, since it is prefixed with `'0'`

```
01010101
```

If you want to interpret this as binary, you add the prefix `'0b'`

```
>>> 0b01010101
85
```

This is the same as representing the number as `int`

```
>>> int(0b01010101)
85
```

And to represent the value as `chr`

```
>>> chr(0b01010101)
'U'
```

Also note the prefix for `hex` is `'0x'`

Comment: Maybe add that in Python2 `01010101` is an octal number (266305) and in Python3 an invalid token.

Comment: But how do we add the '0b'? I only have the number 01010101