# string to single byte in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, byte

I have a python string that looks like this:

```
byte_string = "01100110"
```

I want to turn this into a byte like so:

```
byte_byte = some_function(byte_string) # byte_byte = 0b01100110
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want to turn that string into a single number.  For that you just convert to `int` with a base of 2.

```
byte_byte = int(byte_string, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

After reflecting on the question some more, I think I originally mis-understood your intent, which is reflected in my below "Prior Answer".

I'm thinking [this prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079085/how-to-convert-a-8-bit-number-to-an-actual-byte-in-python) may address your question as well, as it sounds like you want to convert a string of 8 bits into a single byte.
And, as @Mark Ransom has indicated, it would look like this as a decimal code:

```
int(byte_string, 2)
output: 102
```

Or like this as the corresponding ascii character:

```
chr(int(byte_string, 2))
output: 'f'
```

----Prior Answer Based on Assumption of Encoding a String into an array of bytes------

You can encode a string to bytes like this, optionally passing the specific encoding if you want:

```
byte_string = "01100110"
byte_string.encode("utf-8")

bytes(byte_string, 'utf-8')
```

Result:

```
b'01100110'
```

[Link to python docs for encoding / decoding strings](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes).

Another option would be to create a bytearray:

```
bytearray(byte_string, 'utf-8')
output: bytearray(b'01100110')
```

And here is another [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903377/python3-bytes-vs-bytearray-and-converting-to-and-from-strings) that might be helpful as well, describing the difference between bytes and bytearray objects in relation to their use in converting to and from strings.