# storing bytes in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I have to read  UART device through the USB port and store the incoming bytes in a `.txt` file.

I use the following command:

```
while 1:
    x=ser.read()
    f.write(str(x))    #f is the file object
```

However this converts some `bytes` to their corresponding `ascii` characters and stores some as it is

**Example:**

> `b'\x55'` is stored as `b'U'`.
>
> But, `b'\xaa'` is stored as the string itself (i.e. `b'\xaa'`).

If I use `chr(int.from_bytes())` it gives the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\xaa' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Is there a method by which I can store all the incoming bytes as the bytes without converting some to `ascii` characters (eg: `b'\x55'` stored as string `b'\x55'` not `b'U'`), as this causes problems when I process the data further.

I am using python-3.7 on 64 bit windows 10

Comment: How does the `.txt` file look like???

Comment: If your data is not text, you can either store it as is in a binary file, or you will have to encode it to some textual representation. Using `str` as you do does the latter, maybe you want to do the former?

Comment: I'd say you should store the data in binary format as you receive it and then use a hex viewer / editor to open it.

Answer (score 0):

try the following link: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-binary-data-python and also [Python writing binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955543/python-writing-binary)

```
with open("outfile.txt", "br+") as outfile:
   outfile.write(ser.read())
```