# Python: How do I make this regex work when Input is read from file

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> line = '\xc2d sdsdfdslkfsdkfjdsf'
>>> pattern_strings = ['\xc2d', '\xe9']
>>> pattern = '|'.join(pattern_strings)
>>> pattern
'\xc2d|\xe9'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(pattern, line)
['\xc2d']
```

When I put `line` in a file and try to do the same regex, it doen't show up anything

```
def find_pattern(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            pattern_strings = ['\xc2d', '\xe9'] # or using ['\\xc2d', '\xe9'] doesn't help
            pattern = '|'.join(pattern_strings)
            print re.findall(pattern, line)
```

where `path` is a file looked as following
`\xc2d sdsdfdslkfsdkfjdsf`

I see

```
\xc2d
[]
d\xa0
[]
\xe7
[]
\xc3\ufffdd
[]
\xc3\ufffdd
[]
\xc2\xa0
[]
\xc3\xa7
[]
\xa0\xa0
[]
'619d813\xa03697'
[]
```

Comment: Add `print line` to your app to ensure you are reading file properly

Comment: yes @Omnga, the file prints the data correctly

Answer (score 2):

`line = "\xc2d bla"` is a Python string where `"\xc2d" is a substring with 2 characters in it.

Your file sounds like it has the literal string "\xc2d" in it, which wouldn't match that pattern.

If you'd like to match the literal string, you'd need to match each of its characters (so, escape the slash).

```
pattern = r"\\xc2d"
```

Comment: Is there a way to match the literal string with pattern?

Comment: Neither does saying "that doesn't helps out".

Comment: sorry if you feel bad, but yeah I tried the way you said and it doesn't work

Comment: I don't feel bad :). If you'd like help, you need to specify what you tried, and how it didn't work. Just saying "it didn't work" isn't helpful, nor is responding with "what you told me isn't helpful".

Comment: ah, sorry about that, I am continuously making updates to code above

Comment: Oh. Well, you're using non-raw strings, so you need to escape the pattern I gave you, or use a raw string. Edited again to show the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to read file in binary mode `f = open("myfile", "rb")` to prevent `\x` conversion, as in Python `\xhh` represents [hex escape characters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0223/).

Non-binary reading will fail - check [here](http://ideone.com/93txQ).

Comment: Check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python