# Manipulating an OS directory with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a function that allows my Tkinter GUI app user browse a directory and choose a file from it. So far, I have the code to open the directory but I'm having problems with saving a selected file from that directory to a variable that I can play around with.

The code I have so far - :

```
import os
def browsetone(self):
   os.startfile("C:\Users\Chidumaga\Music\music")
```

The music directory is opened but how do I register the selection of a file ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear for me what you are trying to do. Anyway, it is tagged with Tkinter so I guess this is what you need:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
guiRoot = Tk()
startDir = "C:\Users\Chidumaga\Music\music"
someFileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=guiRoot,title='Choose a file',initialdir=startDir)
if(someFileName!=""):
    someFile = open(someFileName,'rb')
    #read file contents
    someFile.close()
guiRoot.mainloop()
```

Obviously opening a file dialog should be triggered by a button click or some similar event. It is up to you. Example of how to read binary file:  [Reading binary file in Python and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python)