# Match a hex string in a binary file in python

Tags: python

I read this post regarding openning a file in binary format:
[Reading binary file in Python and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python)

How can I match a string (as hex value) with a binary file in python:
as an example, i want to match this in a binary file

```
00e4009a00ea00ff00a800cd00930018006b00e10067000e00e0002c00710045
```

How can i compare that with the content in the binary file?

Answer (score 2):

Turn the hexadecimal data into binary before matching:

```
import binascii

pattern = "00e4009a00ea00ff00a800cd00930018006b00e10067000e00e0002c00710045"

if binascii.unhexlify(pattern) in binary_file_contents:
    pass
```