# Input data to a list from a binary file using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a binary file. I need to input each byte into the list I am creating, in such  a way that the whole binary file of hexadecimal numbers is now in a list.
I have tried the following out, but it is not working
f is the binary file

```
f1=[]
f1 = f.read(1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading binary file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this SO answer.

[Reading binary file in Python and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python)

to quote Skurmedel's answer:

```
f = open("myfile", "rb")
try:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a list with the output of the file:

```
f=open('my_binary_file')
my_list=list(f.read())
```

Worked for me here.

Comment: I am not sure whether this comment means that you solved the problem or that you want further help based on the fact that you used a byterray(). For now, I am assuming you solved the problem.