# How to read binary files in Python?

Tags: python, file, binary

I am new to binary files and trying to figure out how to read and manipulate them. I have the following code:

```
bfile = open('square.bmp', 'wb')

b = bytearray(bfile.read(bn))

while len(b) > 0:
    b = bytearray(bfile.read(bn))
    print(b)

bfile.close()
```

However, running this code is throwing errors and I do not know what I can replace the "bn" with or declare it as to run read the entire file.

Comment: Check this other question, it may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python

Comment: `bn` is an undefined variable. Typically, `read()` takes a size as a parameter, so you might want to start there.

Comment: by the way, `open(..., 'wb')` recreates file, so you'll rean nothing

Comment: More fundamentally ;-), you opened the file for writing (`w`), not for reading.  Change the open mode to `'rb'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("square.bmp", "rb") as f:
   b = f.read(1)
   while b != b"":
      b = f.read(1)
```

Comment: Are you checking for EOF or empty string?

Comment: @Keikoku read returns `''` on eof.

Comment: In binary mode, it returns `b''`

Comment: @Keikoku I guess you meand for py3, I'm not used to it