# How to read a simple binary file

Tags: python

I have a binary file that consists of consecutive binary subsequences of fixed and equal length. Each subsequence can be unpacked into the same number of values. I know the length of each subsequence and the binary format of the values.

> How can I work through the binary file, chopping out the subsequences,
>   unpacking their content and write them out as csv as I go.

I know how to write out as csv. My problem is the reading from file and unpacking part.  This is my non-working code.

```
import csv
import sys
import struct
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,escapechar='\\')  
?  rows = sys.stdin. ?
?  header = id, time ....
? write the header with csv
i = 0
for row in rows:
    unpacked_row = unpack('QqqqddiBIBcsbshlshhlQB',row)
    writer.writerow(unpacked_row)
    i += 1
```

---

Possible solution using [Reading binary file in Python and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python) and the answer of ignacio.

First calculate chunksize = struct.calcsize()

```
def bytes_from_file(filename, chunksize=8192):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunksize)
            if chunk:
                yield chunk
            else:
                break

# example:
for chunk in bytes_from_file('filename'):
#        row = unpack(chunk)
#        write out row as csv
```

Comment: Waht is not working? Does `unpack` return what you expect?

Comment: What's `rows`? What constitutes a row of a binary file?

Comment: @martineau It is a mistake. I think I need to read a fixed number of bytes at a time maybe?

Comment: Yes, that's what Ignacio is saying in his answer I believe...and you can read _multiples_ of that fixed number if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the size of the structure (Hint: `struct.calcsize()`) and read some multiple of that from the file at a time. You cannot directly iterate over the input as you can with a text file, since there is no delimiter as such.

Comment: Do I have to use with open("myfile", "rb") as f: ; bytes = f.read(numberofbytes)  ?

Comment: A few more lines than just that, but yes.

Comment: Can you read the whole file into memory and process it there chunk by chunk somehow? I am thinking this might be faster.

Comment: You can read as much as you like. I recommend not reading *too* much though; more than 10MB at a time gains you little.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`struct.Struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#classes) to unpack values from a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import sys
from struct import Struct

record = Struct('QqqqddiBIBcsbshlshhlQB')
with open('input_filename', 'rb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
    while True:
        buf = file.read(record.size)
        if len(buf) != record.size: 
            break
        writer.writerow(record.unpack_from(buf))
```

You could also write the `while`-loop as:

```
from functools import partial

for buf in iter(partial(file.read, record.size), b''):
    writer.writerow(record.unpack_from(buf))
```