# How does this loop works: for item in iter(queue.get, None)?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm using python Queue to store items to be processed by threads. From what I've read online, putting a 'None' object in the queue and setting up the thread processing like this will make the thread stop. (which it does)

```
for item in iter(queue.get, None):
    #do stuff
    queue.task_done()
```

Now I cannot find many information online about this type of for loop. From what I've seen it just ends and will not process anything else which leaves the None object in the queue. 
Adding a queue.task_done() at the end doesn't work.

Can someone explain to me more about this type of for loops. How are they named and how do they work in general, or point me towards some good documentation about it since I cannot find any.

Comment: The key in this loop is an alternative signature to `iter()` - instead of calling it with an iterable, it's used as `iter(callable, sentinel)`, where it will call `callable()` and yield the result until it equals the `sentinel`, indicating the end of iteration. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25611913/1599111) for an easier to understand example.

Comment: Note that you need to add a call to `queue.task_done()` call after the for loop to mark the sentinel task as complete, otherwise `queue.join()` will hang.

Comment: related: [What are the uses of iter(callable, sentinel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38087427/9059420)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [the documentation for the `iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

> If the second argument, *sentinel*, is given, then *o* must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call *o* with no arguments for each call to its `next()` method; if the value returned is equal to *sentinel*, `StopIteration` will be raised, otherwise the value will be returned.

So the loop's behavior is equivalent to:

```
sentinel = None
while True:
  item = queue.get()
  if item == sentinel:
    break
  # do stuff
  queue.task_done()
```

Comment: `is sentinel` or `== sentinel`?

Comment: @Eric: Good catch. Yes, the semantics are those of `== sentinel`. Updated.

Answer (score 8):

This line:

```
for item in iter(queue.get, None):
```

Reads

> "Keep calling `queue.get`, and then run the loop body, until `queue.get() == None`

Answer (score 1):

It is a second form of `iter()`:

> ```
> iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator
> ```
>
> In the second form, the callable is called until it returns the sentinel.

(from `help(iter)`).

So each time for-statement tries to get an element from iterator returned by `iter`, it calls `queue.get()`, checks if returned not None, and passed returned value as `item` to for-statement-body. When somebody pushes None-terminator onto queue, `queue.get()` returns None causing iterator to throw `StopIteration` and interpreter leaves for-statement block.

Answer (score 0):

I think the curial part is that:

> NOTE This will block when there's no element remain and no sentinel value is put.

so basically this method does not automatically run on any queue, you have to put a `None` value to indicate the end of process

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the approaches differ in a specific multiprocessing environment. Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59055187/2319172)