# line in iter(fp.readline, '') rather than line in fp:

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, file-handling

I read builtin function `iter` 's example in [Built-in Functions — Python 3.7.0 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)

```
with open('mydata.txt') as fp:
    for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
        process_line(line)
```

I could not figure out what's the advantage over the following:

```
with open('mydata.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        process_line(line)
```

Could you please provide any hints?

Comment: Actually I think I agree with you, it is useless in this case(?) Since a an empty string is only produced at the EOF I believe. However, if I'm correct, then this is an odd example to use in the docs

Comment: if instead of an empty string, you had `'a\n'` then it would be similar to adding `if line == 'a\n': break` for the 2nd snippet

Comment: Why do you suppose there *is* any advantage?  It's just giving an example of the two-argument form of `iter` there.

Comment: @wim So they are equivalent right? Isn't it a bad example to put in the docs then as it doesn't demonstrate the utility? Maybe they had in mind something more like this `iter(functools.partial(f.read, 1), '')`

Comment: I don't think the example is necessarily bad ("read lines of a file until a certain line is reached"), but i think using an empty string as the "certain line" was not the best choice.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087427/what-are-the-uses-of-itercallable-sentinel

Answer (score 4):

Both will iterate over a generator, without loading the whole file into memory, but the `iter()` version is demonstrating the use of the second argument of `iter()`, "`sentinel`".

From the docs:

> if the value returned is equal to sentinel, StopIteration will be raised

So this code will read from the file, until a line equals `''` and then stop.

This is a strange example, as all lines in the file will have a newline on the end, so this will only trigger at the end of the file anyway (if at all).

Comment: You will only get empty string at the end of file. Blank lines would be a '\n' during iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer to be clearer about that.

Answer (score 1):

As wim and I discussed in the comments, there is *no advantage* for this particular case. For the 2nd code snippet to be equivalent to the first code snippet then it would look something like this:

```
with open('mydata.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line == '':
            break
        process_line(line)
```

However, the only case an empty string can be returned by `readline` is at the end of the file (EOF) so it makes now difference here (other lines contain a newline `'\n'` character at least).

If rather than an empty string another value was used, then the difference would be meaningful though. Personally, I think the docs should use a better example to illustrate this, like as follows:

```
>>> f = open('test')
>>> f.read()
'a\nb\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n\n'
>>> f = open('test')
>>> [line for line in iter(f.readline, 'b\n')]
['a\n']
>>> f = open('test')
>>> [line for line in f]
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', '\n', 'd\n', 'e\n', 'f\n', '\n']
```

(Note I should really be closing the file handles)

EDIT: I raised this as a possible documentation bug in [issue34764](https://bugs.python.org/issue34764)