# Calling a method other than run in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-multithreading

I am learning about threading in Python and I'm confused about the following code, which I wrote. After starting the Heartbeat thread, how does the `stuff` method call work relative to the `run` method? Is there a race condition regarding `i` and, if so, how would I prevent that?

I'm wondering if this type of construction can be effectively used to communicate with a thread. I do not understand how it works under the hood, however, in terms of method calls in the `Heartbeat` class after `run` is activated. I'm assuming `sleep` allows `stuff` to execute, but I don't know why. I may be over-complicating this and missing something obvious; my lack of intuition, however, is unsettling. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
   1 import threading
   2 import time
   3 
   4 class Heartbeat(threading.Thread):
   5   def __init__(self, delay):
   6     threading.Thread.__init__(self, daemon = True)
   7     self.delay = delay
   8     self.i = 0
   9   
  10   def run(self):
  11     while True:
  12       print("i = {}".format(self.i))
  13       time.sleep(self.delay)
  14   
  15   def stuff(self, i):
  16     self.i = i
  17 
  18 if __name__ == "__main__":
  19   hbThread = Heartbeat(3)
  20   hbThread.start()
  21   
  22   i = 0
  23   while True:
  24     time.sleep(1)
  25     i += 1
  26     hbThread.stuff(i)
```

And the output:

```
i = 0
i = 2
i = 5
i = 8
i = 11
```

Edit: In my opinion, this question is different than the suggested duplicate question for a few reasons. This is a much simpler question with a very specific point while the other is a broad question about multithreading in general. The answers are very helpful, but I don't see any that explain the inner-workings of my situation nor was there an explanation of other methods being called from a different thread as far as I could tell. If it's there, it may be beyond the scope of a beginner to fully comprehend; this question is simpler and more to the point, so I think it has a place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)

Comment: @stovfl I read that thread, but I didn't see an answer to my question. I think the answers in that thread are helpful, but more complex than the nature of my question I believe. The answer to my question by Darkonaut is exactly what I was hoping to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inherit from `Thread` your instance will be like a person standing with one foot in the kitchen and with one foot in the living room. In which thread a method will run depends on from which thread you call it. `run` will be the main-function in the new thread and every method it calls runs there. If you call `stuff` from the parent, it will run in the MainThread. Because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), only one thread can run at a time. A thread in Python 3 would hold the GIL (and hence be able to execute Python code) by default for up to 5 ms, or drop it earlier when doing blocking I/O (like your `time.sleep`). All threads in a process share the same memory so you can append to the instance from the new thread and from the MainThread and both will have access to the data.

Comment: Thanks. I think this answers my question perfectly and succinctly. To make sure I understand, the main thread, so to speak, is running `stuff` and that's perfectly fine to do, right? I think the other part of this is the `run` method, which is the only method in `Heartbeat` that runs in the new thread because it doesn't make any other calls. Thanks for your answer and contribution.

Comment: @Anthony It doesn't make much sense to call `stuff` from the MainThread, let `run` handle it for clarity. But you can set flags from the MainThread on the instance for example and the child-thread would check that flag to know when to exit.

Comment: I should have clarified - my intent isn't to necessarily run the logic of `Heartbeat`. I am trying to figure out how to read/write values to/from the new thread and also I want to be able to terminate the thread using flags. Presuming I don't do much else in `stuff` or other methods like it, does my use case fit the code I wrote or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Anthony For data exchange between the two threads yes, but I would restrict it to start and final data and not intermediate calculation steps like in your example.  Keep it simple, restrict calls from the parent to managing-calls. If you need also intermediate data exchange between the threads I would prefer using a  `queue.Queue`.

Comment: @Anthony Example for basic usage of `queue.Queue` in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53432672/9059420)

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.