# Python multiprocessing returns queue is empty when actually it is not

Tags: python, parallel-processing, queue, multiprocessing

In this program, after some iterations all the processes terminate which means that input_queue is empty as per the condition in target function. But after returning to the main function when I print the input_queue there are still items left in that queue, then why those multiple processes terminated at first place?

```
import cv2
import timeit
import face_recognition
import queue
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import multiprocessing
import os

s = timeit.default_timer()

def alternative_process_target_func(input_queue, output_queue):

    while not input_queue.empty():
        try:
            frame_no, small_frame, face_loc = input_queue.get(False)  # or input_queue.get_nowait()
            print('Frame_no: ', frame_no, 'Process ID: ', os.getpid(), '----', multiprocessing.current_process())

        except queue.Empty:
            print('___________________________________ Breaking __________________________________________________')
            break  # stop when there is nothing more to read from the input


def alternative_process(file_name):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)
    frame_no = 1
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    print('Frames Per Second: ', fps)
    print('Total Number of frames: ', length)
    print('Duration of file: ', int(length / fps))
    processed_frames = 1
    not_processed = 1
    frames = []
    process_this_frame = True
    frame_no = 1
    Input_Queue = Queue()
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print('Size of input Queue: ', Input_Queue.qsize())
            print('Total no of frames read: ', frame_no)
            end1 = timeit.default_timer()
            print('Time taken to fetch useful frames: ', end1 - start)
            threadn = cv2.getNumberOfCPUs()
            Output_Queue = Queue(maxsize=Input_Queue.qsize())
            process_list = []
            #quit = multiprocessing.Event()
            #foundit = multiprocessing.Event()

            for x in range((threadn - 1)):
                # print('Process No : ', x)
                p = Process(target=alternative_process_target_func, args=(Input_Queue, Output_Queue))#, quit, foundit
                p.daemon = True
                #print('I am a new process with process id of: ', os.getpid())
                p.start()
                process_list.append(p)
                #p.join()

            i = 1
            for proc in process_list:
                print('I am hanged here and my process id is : ', os.getpid())
                proc.join()
                print('I have been joined and my process id is : ', os.getpid())
                i += 1

            for value in range(Output_Queue.qsize()):
                print(Output_Queue.get())

            end = timeit.default_timer()
            print('Time taken by face verification: ', end - start)
            print('--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

            #Here I am again printing the Input Queue which should be empty logically.
            for frame in range(Input_Queue.qsize()):
                frame_no, _, _ = Input_Queue.get()
                print(frame_no)

            break

        if process_this_frame:
            print(frame_no)
            small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
            rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
            # frames.append((rgb_small_frame, face_locations))
            Input_Queue.put((frame_no, rgb_small_frame, face_locations))
            frame_no += 1

        if processed_frames < 5:
            processed_frames += 1
            not_processed = 1

        else:
            if not_processed < 15:
                process_this_frame = False
                not_processed += 1
            else:

                processed_frames = 1
                process_this_frame = True
                print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#chec_queues()
#compare_images()
#fps_finder()
alternative_process('user_verification_2.avi')#'hassan_checking.avi'
```

Comment: [how-to-use-multiprocessing-queue-get-method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53132498/9059420)

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains `while not input_queue.empty()`. I guess during the work `input_queue` becomes empty, while loop stops and then you add something else to `input_queue` to process this something else. But it's too late at that moment.

Usually you work with queues like this:

```
while True:
    element = my_queue.get()
    ...
```

To stop this loop you may count number of treated elements, use `timeout` argument or kill process under some condition. Another option is to use `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: No I'm not adding anything extra into Input Queue after that while loop in the target function. However I was to able to get that right by using Manager.queue but I still don't know why the earlier one was not working and why using manager queues resolves the error.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan Looking at the code I see that you do `p.start()` before `Input_Queue.put((frame_no, rgb_small_frame, face_locations))`.

Comment: No, the "if not ret" condition makes sure that, no items are added into the input queue after processes start.

Comment: @Muhammadhassan The logic behind the code is obscured to me. What I see is the following - if `ret` becomes `False` after some time then you may get unlimited amount of frames in the `input_queue` because once every 20 steps `process_this_frame` is `True` (or 5 out of 20?). Please understand the logic of your own code. I guess you should re-organize the code.