# How to pass unpickled object as argument in multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I am unpickling an object and passing as one of the args for process.Getting no output.

I want to know if this method of unpickling and passing an object as argument is causing any error for multiprocessing. What will be work around for this?

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
def func(arg1, arg2,q):
    df_temp = arg1[arg1['col'].isin(arg2)]
    q.put(df_temp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pickle
    import pandas as pd
    arg1= pickle.load(open('paths.p','rb'))
    arg2= pd.Series(pd.date_range(end = 'some_Date', periods=12,freq = 'MS')).dt.to_pydatetime()
    arg2=[i.date() for i in arg2]
    q = Queue()
    p =Process(target=func, args=(arg1,arg2,q))
    p.start()
    p.join()    
    while not q.empty():
        w=q.get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are deadlocking for other reasons.

> By default if a process is not the creator of the queue then on exit
>   it will attempt to join the queue’s background thread. The process can
>   call cancel_join_thread() to make join_thread() do nothing. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.join_thread)

Your `Process` won't exit because it is joining a feeder thread from `multiprocessing.Queue`, which gets started as soon as you `queue.put()` the first time. You need to `queue.get()` in your parent *before* you join the process.

> **Warning:** As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a
>   queue (and it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread), then
>   that process will not terminate until all buffered items have been
>   flushed to the pipe. This means that if you try joining that process
>   you may get a deadlock unless you are sure that all items which have
>   been put on the queue have been consumed. Similarly, if the child
>   process is non-daemonic then the parent process may hang on exit when
>   it tries to join all its non-daemonic children.  [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)

Also don't use `while not q.empty()`, it's an anti-pattern which will lead to deadlocks as soon as you have multiple consumers.
Use sentinel-values instead to notify the consumer that no further items are coming. More about this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53132779/9059420).