# Why does stdin read line by line rather than word by word like a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, iteration, sys

program1.py:

```
a = "this is a test"
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

program2.py:

```
a = """this is a test
       with more than one line
       three, to be exact"""
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

program3.py:

```
import sys

for x in sys.stdin:
    print(x)
```

infile.txt:

> This is a test
>   with multiple lines
>   just the same as the second example
>   but with more words

Why do program1 and program2 both output each character in the string on a separate line, but if we run `cat infile.txt | python3 program3.py`, it outputs the text line by line?

Comment: because `sys.stdin` is not a string - it is special class which was constructed to read line by line.

Comment: `sys.stdin` is *not a `str`* object, it is a file-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description of `sys.stdin`, from the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html):

> File objects corresponding to the interpreter’s standard input, output and error streams.

So `sys.stdin` is a file object, not a string. To see how the iterator for File objects work, look at, once again, the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> When a file is used as an iterator, typically in a for loop (for example, for line in f: print line.strip()), the next() method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or raises StopIteration when EOF is hit when the file is open for reading (behavior is undefined when the file is open for writing)

So, the iterator yields the next line of input at every call, instead of the character-by-character iteration observed on strings.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.stdin` is a file handle. Iterating on a file handle produces one line at a time.

Comment: You can change this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611796/how-to-read-in-one-character-at-a-time-from-a-file-in-python

Answer (score -2):

Because data in `sys.stdin` is stored like array of lines so when you run `for x in sys.stdin` it is taking one by one lines not characters. To do that what you want try this:

```
for x in sys.stdin:
    for y in x:
        print(y)
    print("")
```

Comment: `sys.stdin` does not store data split into lines. This has nothing to do with storage details.