# Django rest frame work - File upload fails in test but working everywhere else

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to test an image upload field with django 1.7, DRF 2.4.3 and Pillow 2.6.1.

File upload is working properly from the admin and when i test using curl

```
curl -X POST -S -H 'Accept: application/json' -F 'my_image=@hm.jpg;type=image/jpg' http://localhost:8000/api/randomresource/
```

When i ran a similar test in an `APITestCase`

```
temp_file = open('hm.jpg',"r")
response = self.client.post('randomresource', {"my_image":temp_file}, format='multipart')
self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I get

```
{'my_image': [u'Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.']}
```

Appreciate any help with this one. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `rb` flag instead of `r`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@mariodev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566605/mariodev) answered this in the comments yesterday:

> Have you tried the rb flag instead of r?

This is because otherwise you uploading the file with an encoding. For text files, and other non-binary files, this shouldn't be an issue, but for cases such as image files [you need to open it as a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1035340/359284).

```
temp_file = open('hm.jpg',"rb")
```

When Django REST Framework checks that the image is valid using `Pillow`, it will raise an exception if the encoding is wrong. This is why you are getting the error, as Django REST Framework got a file upload, but can't verify that it is an image. The encoding was correct when using curl, because curl was uploading it as a binary file and was handling it all for you.