# Own implement encoding and decoding base64 files in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, base64, decoding

I have a problem with my own implementation of base64 encoding.  I have achieved to get the code below. It only works for text files with the English Letters, I suppose. For instance pdf file is encoded and decoded, it differs single characters.

```
def base64Encode(data):
    alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","+","/"]
    bit_str = ""      
    base64_str = ""

    for char in data:
        bin_char = bin(char).lstrip("0b")
        bin_char = bin_char.zfill(8)
        bit_str += bin_char 

    brackets = [bit_str[x:x+6] for x in range(0,len(bit_str),6)]

    for bracket in brackets:
        if(len(bracket) < 6):
            bracket = bracket + (6-len(bracket))*"0" 
        base64_str += alphabet[int(bracket,2)]

    # print(brackets[-4:])
    #if(bracket[-1:)
    #print(len(base64_str))
    #if(len(base64_str) != 76):
    #    base64_str += "="

    return base64_str

def base64Decode(text):
        alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","+","/"]
        bit_str = ""
        text_str = ""

        for char in text:
            if char in alphabet:
                bin_char = bin(alphabet.index(char)).lstrip("0b")
                bin_char = bin_char.zfill(6)
                bit_str += bin_char

        brackets = [bit_str[x:x+8] for x in range(0,len(bit_str),8)]

        for bracket in brackets:
            text_str += chr(int(bracket,2))

        return text_str.encode("UTF-8")

w = open("encode.txt", "w") 
with open("bla.txt", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(57)
    while byte:
        w.write(base64Encode(byte))
        w.write("\n")
        byte = f.read(57)
    w.close()
f.close()

w = open("decode.txt", "wb") 
with open("encode.txt", "r") as f:
    byte = f.read(77)
    while byte:
        w.write(base64Decode(byte))
        byte = f.read(77)
    w.close()
f.close()
```

In my opinion, this line "return text_str.encode (" UTF-8 ")" should be without decoding to UTF-8. However, if you leave only "return text_str", gets error: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface.

bla.txt:

```
Phil Mercer reports on Cyclone Pam which has ravaged the Pacific nation of Vanuatu. Video courtesy of YouTube/Isso Nihmei at 350.org

Save the Children's Vanuatu country director Tom Skirrow said on Saturday: "The scene here this morning is complete devastation - houses are destroyed, trees are down, roads are blocked and people are wandering the streets looking for help.

ĄŚĆŹŻÓ
```

encode.txt

```
UGhpbCBNZXJjZXIgcmVwb3J0cyBvbiBDeWNsb25lIFBhbSB3aGljaCBoYXMgcmF2YWdlZCB0aGUg
UGFjaWZpYyBuYXRpb24gb2YgVmFudWF0dS4gVmlkZW8gY291cnRlc3kgb2YgWW91VHViZS9Jc3Nv
IE5paG1laSBhdCAzNTAub3JnDQoNClNhdmUgdGhlIENoaWxkcmVuJ3MgVmFudWF0dSBjb3VudHJ5
IGRpcmVjdG9yIFRvbSBTa2lycm93IHNhaWQgb24gU2F0dXJkYXk6ICJUaGUgc2NlbmUgaGVyZSB0
aGlzIG1vcm5pbmcgaXMgY29tcGxldGUgZGV2YXN0YXRpb24gLSBob3VzZXMgYXJlIGRlc3Ryb3ll
ZCwgdHJlZXMgYXJlIGRvd24sIHJvYWRzIGFyZSBibG9ja2VkIGFuZCBwZW9wbGUgYXJlIHdhbmRl
cmluZyB0aGUgc3RyZWV0cyBsb29raW5nIGZvciBoZWxwLg0KDQrEhMWaxIbFucW7w5M
```

decode.txt

```
Phil Mercer reports on Cyclone Pam which has ravaged the Pacific nation of Vanuatu. Video courtesy of YouTube/Isso Nihmei at 350.org

Save the Children's Vanuatu country director Tom Skirrow said on Saturday: "The scene here this morning is complete devastation - houses are destroyed, trees are down, roads are blocked and people are wandering the streets looking for help.

ÄÅÄÅ¹Å»Ã
```

The same text encoded by page: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

```
UGhpbCBNZXJjZXIgcmVwb3J0cyBvbiBDeWNsb25lIFBhbSB3aGljaCBoYXMgcmF2YWdlZCB0aGUg
UGFjaWZpYyBuYXRpb24gb2YgVmFudWF0dS4gVmlkZW8gY291cnRlc3kgb2YgWW91VHViZS9Jc3Nv
IE5paG1laSBhdCAzNTAub3JnDQoNClNhdmUgdGhlIENoaWxkcmVuJ3MgVmFudWF0dSBjb3VudHJ5
IGRpcmVjdG9yIFRvbSBTa2lycm93IHNhaWQgb24gU2F0dXJkYXk6ICJUaGUgc2NlbmUgaGVyZSB0
aGlzIG1vcm5pbmcgaXMgY29tcGxldGUgZGV2YXN0YXRpb24gLSBob3VzZXMgYXJlIGRlc3Ryb3ll
ZCwgdHJlZXMgYXJlIGRvd24sIHJvYWRzIGFyZSBibG9ja2VkIGFuZCBwZW9wbGUgYXJlIHdhbmRl
cmluZyB0aGUgc3RyZWV0cyBsb29raW5nIGZvciBoZWxwLg0KDQrEhMWaxIbFucW7w5M=
```

It is the same, except "=", which omitted to implement due to the error at the very beginning of the file.

And sample originale file in pdf:

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(pl-PL) /StructTreeRoot 8 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 110>>
stream
xœUÌ­
€@à¾°ï0QËÝ®Èiž?(†kb°hòý«ZD˜4ßÀÎ¨*;…¡xº  ¨#“íªFrÄI!w…˜2ËQ81®D<™ÇS=Ó’léŠ82µ·>^åŒÊO-  >[´SÀ 
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/TrueType/Name/F1/BaseFont/ABCDEE+Calibri/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FontDescriptor 6 0 R/FirstChar 32/LastChar 97/Widths 15 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/ABCDEE+Calibri/Flags 32/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 750/Descent -250/CapHeight 750/AvgWidth 521/MaxWidth 1743/FontWeight 400/XHeight 250/StemV 52/FontBBox[ -503 -250 1240 750] /FontFile2 16 0 R>>
endobj
7 0 obj
```

And after executing script:

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(pl-PL) /StructTreeRoot 8 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 110>>
stream
xUÌ­
@à¾°ï0QËÝ®Èi?(kb°hòý«ZD4ßÀÎ¨*;¡xº  ¨#íªFrÄI!w2ËQ81®D<ÇS=Ólé82µ·>^åÊO-  >[´SÀ 
endstream
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/TrueType/Name/F1/BaseFont/ABCDEE+Calibri/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FontDescriptor 6 0 R/FirstChar 32/LastChar 97/Widths 15 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type/FontDescriptor/FontName/ABCDEE+Calibri/Flags 32/ItalicAngle 0/Ascent 750/Descent -250/CapHeight 750/AvgWidth 521/MaxWidth 1743/FontWeight 400/XHeight 250/StemV 52/FontBBox[ -503 -250 1240 750] /FontFile2 16 0 R>>
endobj
7 0 obj
```

The differences are for instance at the beginning of line 15 and 16.

My goal is to load the file and encode it in base64 and then decode and obtain the same file. Fit for use.
I suppose that the error is in the data read or write or encoding. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this task. Replace line .encode("UTF-8") on .encode ("latin-1") and It works at least for pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is troubleshooting: Determine if you are failing to encode or decode properly or both. Encode the file using a working utility and with your app and compare. Decode a properly encoded file with your app and with a working utility and compare.
Second suggestion: Deal with the data as individual bytes, not text that may be interpreted as UTF-8.

Open the PDF file in binary mode. See [Reading binary file in Python and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python) on how to do that. Pass the raw bytes to your base64Encode. Do not use the bin function to convert from string to binary.

Comment: I have shown above that the encoding seems to be correct. Compared with an external encoder base64 given in the link. I tried to write bytes but there is a problem I described above. I use the wrong function?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the original code. This works on text, PNG and PDF, I haven't tried other file types, but I expect it will work on them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Mar 16 07:38:19 2019

@author: tracyanne
"""
import os

class Base64():

    def __init__(self):

        ## We only need to do this once
        self.b64 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","+","/"]


    def Encode(self, data):
        alphabet = self.b64
        bit_str = ""
        base64_str = ""

        for char in data:
            bin_char = bin(char).lstrip("0b")
            bin_char = bin_char.zfill(8)
            bit_str += bin_char

        brackets = [bit_str[x:x+6] for x in range(0,len(bit_str),6)]

        for bracket in brackets:
            if(len(bracket) < 6):
                bracket = bracket + (6-len(bracket))*"0"
            base64_str += alphabet[int(bracket,2)]

        ##Add padding characters to maintain compatibility with forced padding
        padding_indicator = len(base64_str) % 4
        if padding_indicator == 3:
            base64_str += "="
        elif  padding_indicator == 2:
            base64_str += "=="

        return base64_str

    def Decode(self, text, eof):
        alphabet = self.b64
        bit_str = ""
        text_str = ""

        for char in text:
            if char in alphabet:
                bin_char = bin(alphabet.index(char)).lstrip("0b")
                bin_char = bin_char.zfill(6)
                bit_str += bin_char

        brackets = [bit_str[x:x+8] for x in range(0,len(bit_str),8)]

        for bracket in brackets:
            ## When eof ignore last value in brackets to remove \x00
            if eof and brackets[len(brackets) -1] == bracket:
                pass
            else:
                text_str += chr(int(bracket,2))

        ## encode string as Latin-1 == ISO-8859-1
        return text_str.encode("ISO-8859-1")

    def base64Encode(self, inFile, outFile):
        w = open(outFile, "w")
        with open(inFile, "rb") as f:
            byte = f.read(57)
            while byte:
                w.write(self.Encode(byte))
                w.write("\n")
                byte = f.read(57)
            w.close()
        f.close()

    def base64Decode(self, inFile, outFile):
        ## Get size of input file for later comparison
        fsize = os.path.getsize(inFile)
        incsize = 0
        eof = False

        w = open(outFile, "wb")
        with open(inFile, "r") as f:
            byte = f.read(77)
            while byte:
                ## keep current dataread and if current data read ==
                ## input file size set eof True
                incsize += len(byte)
                if fsize - incsize == 0:
                    eof = True
                ## Pass in eof to Decode
                w.write(base64.base64Decode(byte, eof))
                byte = f.read(77)
            w.close()
        f.close()
```

Comment: Could you explain how it works and fix your editing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by fix the editing. But save the Code as MyBase64.py the following is the code I used to test it