# python2.7: reading journald's binary log

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, binary, systemd

I'm currently working on a parser for plaso. For this I need to read journald's binary log files and convert those to a plaso timeline object.

My question now is: How do I read a binary file in python, keeping in mind that the file may contain strings and integers. Is a byte array sufficient for this? If so, how can I find the correct delimiters for the message fields?

Since I'm new to python I can't provide useful code just yet, still trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Is this 2.7 or 3.x? Python made huge changes to the way binary is read.

Comment: oh, sorry, I'll edit this in. It's python 2.7

Comment: Maybe the [Journal File Format](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/journal-files/) doc and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python) could help you

Comment: Thank you for your input, Mauro. I already read the doc, the problem I had is more along the lines of "How do I get my file into something I can use?" And I wasn't sure, if looping over every single byte was the pythonic way to do this.

Comment: You could always read the journal in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with binary data using [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) package.

If I had been you I would have seen the struct of the file by journald (from journald docs or its source code) and parsed binary data into fields.

Comment: This is what I tried to do. I just wasn't sure how to handle the parsing. Maybe the struct package is the key to this. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidMändlen yes, reading the binary file is simple itself. You should use proper `format` string according to journald docs.