# Splitting binary file content in two parts using single byte separator in python

Tags: python, string, file, split, stream

I have a file consisting in three parts:

1. Xml header (unicode);
2. ASCII character `29` (group separator);
3. A numeric stream to the end of file

I want to get one xml string from the first part, and the numeric stream (to be parsed with `struct.unpack` or `array.fromfile`).

Should I create an empty string and add to it reading the file byte by byte until I find the separator, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1035360/401828)?

Or is there a way to read everything and use something like `xmlstring = open('file.dat', 'rb').read().split(chr(29))[0]` (which by the way doesn't work) ?

EDIT: this is what I see using a hex editor: the separator is there (selected byte)

[image]

Comment: In what way does `.split(29)` not work? Does it produce an error message? Please provide a short, complete program that demonstrates the error you are having.

Comment: Can you show an sample input and expected output of your file?

Comment: It would be a bit difficult for me to create code right now (I am already receiving the file generated elsewhere).

Comment: The code you have pasted works fine for me. In what way does it not work for you?

Comment: @Robᵩ it returns the whole file, not just the part before `chr(29)` .

Comment: Then you probably don't have a `29` byte in your file.

Comment: You should be using `with open` with anyways, it simplifies exception handling with some encapsulation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3012921

Comment: @Robᵩ the byte is there, see my attached screencapture.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think this is my problem. It appears as a `)/` in the editor and when I just print the string to the console. What have I lost here?

Comment: It would make more sense if it was an actual 29 (i.e. 0x1d) instead, since 0x29 is a ")". But that is a source error.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I talked to a coworker, and indeed the C# code generating the file was erroneously using `0x29` as separator. We are fixing that, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt at searching for the value `chr(29)` didn't work because in that expression `29` is a value in decimal notation. The value you got from your hex editor however is displayed in hex, so it's `0x29` (or `41` in decimal).

You can simply do the conversion in Python - `0xnn` is just another notation for entering an integer literal:

```
>>> 0x29
41
```

You can then use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to split the data into your respective parts:

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    data = infile.read()

xml, sep, binary_data = data.partition(SEP)
```

**Demonstration**:

```
import random

SEP = chr(0x29)


with open('file.dat', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write("<doc></doc>")
    outfile.write(SEP)
    data = ''.join(chr(random.randint(0, 255)) for i in range(1024))
    outfile.write(data)


with open('file.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    data = infile.read()

xml, sep, binary_data = data.partition(SEP)

print xml
print len(binary_data)
```

Output:

```
<doc></doc>
1024
```

Comment: This gives me the whole file as first element, and two aditional empty strings

Comment: Then your file simply does not contain the ASCII character 29 - might it be that 29 is in hex notation instead of decimal? Try `chr(0x29)` as the separator instead like in my updated answer.

Comment: The byte is there, see my attached screencapture.

Comment: @Tui Popenoe you don't say... My suggestion was that `29` was already the hex representation, and therefore the correct value to search for would be decimal `41`. If you just substitute decimal `29` with `0x1d` you don't change a thing.

Comment: @heltonbiker yes, the hex editor displays the values in hex, so `chr(0x29)` or `chr(41)` is the correct value to search for.

Comment: @LukasGraf it worked with `file.read().partition(chr(41))`. Now how the hell should I have made the conversion?

Comment: it also worked as you said: `...partition(chr(0x29))`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are reading the file in before trying to split it. In your code, your don't have a `.read()`

```
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as f:
    file = f.read()
    if chr(29) in file:
        xmlstring = file.split(chr(29))[0]
    elif hex(29) in file:
        xmlstring = file.split(hex(29))[0]
    else:
        xmlstring = '\x1d not found!'
```

Ensure that a ASCII 29 char exists in your file (`\x1d`)

Comment: Thanks, there was a typo in my sample code. I was already doing this, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Regarding your last phrase, the group separator byte can be seen in a HexEditor.

Answer (score 1):

[mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) the file, search for the 29, create a `buffer` or `memoryview` from the first part to feed to the parser, and pass the rest through `struct`.

Comment: Would it be better than simply reading one byte at a time until finding the separator byte, or else loading the whole file to a `StringIO` and performing the same search in memory?

Comment: A mmapped file exists as a byte array in the file cache; either of those options will be both slower and less flexible.