# Reading Parts of Large Binary File in Python

Tags: python, binaryfiles, large-data

I want to read in a random chunk from a large binary data file in Python and so far I have not found a good solution to my problem.

What I have so far is the following, but it only can read in the first *n* integers and cannot start somewhere else in the file.

```
import numpy as np  
#Pick an n here.

f = open("test2.rd14")
a = np.fromfile(f, dtype = np.uint16, count=int(n))
```

Also the file in too large to use

```
with open("test2.rd14") as file:
filecontent = file.read()
```

Comment: You should probably check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-in-python-and-looping-over-each-byte) it might be of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in the docs.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Open it in binary mode

```
f = open("test2.rd14", "rb")
```

and then you want to use the seek method,

```
f.seek(byte_n)
```

to start elsewhere.

Comment: worth adding that f.read(n_bytes) would read n bytes from byte n if called after the seek