# memory error in python while processing large file

Tags: python-2.6

Input: large file around 12GB with sequence file, with ~ delimiter and I want to break after every 10th occurrence with new line.

I tried with

```
with open ("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        x = line.count("~")
        y = line.split("~")
        s = ['Ç'.join(x) for x in [y[i:i + 10] for i in xrange(0, len(y), 10)]]
with open ("output.txt","w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("~\n".join(s))
```

While `line.split('~')` I'am getting memory error.

I tried with `y = [line.split('~') for line in f]` but no use same error. Please assist me how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in f:
```

will try to load all file into your RAM

Use xreadline iterator to load file line by line:

```
for line in f.xreadlines():
```

Comment: after changing to for line in f.xreadlines(): still am facing memory error for this line y = line.split("~").

Comment: Check the size of a line. If you don't have proper end of line symbols in your file then all file will be read into one line. In that case you have to read your file as binary using a buffer. See example in following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte

Comment: i tried with binary as well but no use again same memory error

Comment: outfile.write("~\n".join(s))
will also load everything into the memory
try to use: for item in s: outfile.write(item+'\n')

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html
could be useful for understanding of file opertions

Comment: my input file is in sequence format and no end at the line, still am facing memory error issue