# How do I copy a chunk of a binary file in Python?

Tags: python, file, buffer, binaryfiles

I have a big binary file (60GB) that I want to split into several smaller. I iterated over the file and found the points at which I want to split the file using `fileObject.tell()` method, so now I have an array of 1000 split points called `file_pointers`. I am looking for a way to create files out of those split points, so the function would look like:

```
def split_file(file_object, file_pointers):
     # Do something here
```

and it would create files for every chunk. I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I am afraid Python's looping could be too slow, and I also feel like there must be some kind of a built-in function that should something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot simpler than I thought, but I will post my answer in here just in case anyone wants a quick solution. Here is an example of copying from `file_pointer[1]` to `file_pointer[2]`

```
with open('train_example.bson', 'rb') as fbson:
    fbson.seek(file_pointers[1])
    bytes_chunk = fbson.read(file_pointers[2] - file_pointers[1])
    with open('tmp.bson', 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(bytes_chunk)
```