# Sending binary image through pipes in python to a C server

Tags: c, python-3.x, binary, named-pipes

so i'm trying to send a file (in this case a .jpg image) in binary from a client in python 3 to a C server through pipes and for some reason it displays the error, broken pipe, here is the code: 
python:

```
import os,sys,errno,pipes,signal,time     

def Tuberia():
    fifo = "/tmp/fifoNombre"
    print ("conecting to a pipe...",fifo)
    file = open("/home/luisro/Pictures/64.jpg","r+b")
    f = open(fifo,'wb')
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        f.write(line)
    f.close()
    file.close()
```

and the C server:

```
void reciveFile(){
  int fn;
  char * fifoNombre = "/tmp/fifoNombre";
  // //opens the pipe for reading
  mkfifo(fifoNombre, 0666);
  unsigned char datos[MAX_BUF];
  fn = open(fifoNombre, O_RDONLY);
    read(fn, datos, MAX_BUF);
    saving(datos,"/home/luisro/Desktop/algo.jpg");
   unlink(fifoNombre);

}


void saving(unsigned char *data, char* dirDest){
    FILE *flujoArchivo = fopen(dirDest, "wb");
    if(flujoArchivo == NULL){
        printf("Error saving.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int writed_size = fwrite(data, sizeof(unsigned char), MAX_BUF, flujoArchivo);

    fclose(flujoArchivo);
}
```

so those are the functions i don't know if is the python client or the C server where the problem is, thanks in advance

Comment: is /tmp/fifoNombre ever populated?

Comment: yep the server creates it

Answer (score 1):

A binary file is not "line" oriented, which is how your attempting to read it in python.... Here's a link showing how to read a binary file in python: [The-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte)

Additionally, you may have to change your server to perform some looping when it is receiving the binary file, if it is greater than MAX_BUF.

Answer (score 0):

so i solve it with out any loop this way:

```
def Tuberia():
print("sending file")
    fifo = "/tmp/fifoNombre"
    print ("connecting to pipe...",fifo)
    try:
        f = open(fifo,'wb')
        with open("/home/luisro/Pictures/64.jpg","r+b") as file:
            line = file.read()
            f.write(line)
            print("sending succesfully...")
    except:
        print("problem connecting to pipe\n")
        Tuberia()
    print("closing conexions....")    
    time.sleep(2)
    file.close() 
    f.close()
```

the other problem is the file weights 996.9 kb and when it's send it weights 8.3 mb wich is the size of MAX_BUF in the C server does any one know how to send the correct size for any file?

here is the C server:

```
void reciveFile(){
  int fn;
  char * fifoNombre = "/tmp/fifoNombre";
  // //opens the pipe for reading
  mkfifo(fifoNombre, 0666);
  unsigned char datos[MAX_BUF];
  fn = open(fifoNombre, O_RDONLY);
    read(fn, datos, MAX_BUF);
    saving(datos,"/home/luisro/Desktop/algo.jpg");
   unlink(fifoNombre);

}


void saving(unsigned char *data, char* dirDest){
    FILE *flujoArchivo = fopen(dirDest, "wb");
    if(flujoArchivo == NULL){
        printf("Error saving.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int writed_size = fwrite(data, sizeof(unsigned char), MAX_BUF, flujoArchivo);

    fclose(flujoArchivo);
}
```