# How to find byte at specific index from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, indexing, byte

I need to print byte at specific position in file that i know path. So I open default file in "rb" mode and then I need to know what byte is on 15 position. It is posible ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects – see the end of the section, about `seek`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte

Comment: seek set up pointer at specific position it's used when I need to write to file from that pointer but not exactly when i want to read.

Comment: no,seek sets the pointer  - both for reading and writing.

Comment: @Walucas Let's assume that I have 20mb file and I need to know what byte is at position 16 and (size - 16) position dont think that good way is to print all 20kk bytes because it need to be fast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can achieve this with `seek`:

```
with open('my_file', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(15)
    f.read(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this is to read the entire document and slice it:

First read the contense of the file:

```
file = open('test.txt', 'rb')
a = file.read()
```

Then take the desired value:

```
b = a[14]
```

Then don't forget to close the file afterwards:

```
file.close()
```

Or so that is closes automatically:

```
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as file:

    a = file.read()
    b = a[14]
```

Comment: Use a context manager so that the files is closed whatever happens. Also, I think the OP is thinking big files (see question comments) so loading the whole file might not be an option.