# Convert readBin R into Python

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to convert some code using the readBin function (R) into Python.

R code:

```
datFile = file("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/bintest.dat", "rb")
i<-readBin(datFile, integer(), n = 4, size=8, endian = "little", signed=FALSE)
print(i)
```

Returns:

```
[1] 1 3 5 7
```

My attempt in Python:

```
with open("bintest.dat", "rb") as datfile:
    i = int.from_bytes(datfile.read(8), byteorder='little', signed=False)
    print(i)
```

Returns:

```
8589934593
```

How can I get the same output in Python (I know that I'm missing the n parameter, but I can't find a way to implement it properly).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open("bintest.dat", "rb") as f:
    # this is exactly the same as 'n = 4' in R code
    n = 4
    count = 0
    byte = f.read(4)
    while count < n and byte != b"":
        i = int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder='little', signed=False)
        print(i)
        count += 1
        # this is analogue of 'size=8' in R code
        byte = f.read(4)
        byte = f.read(4)
```

Or you can do it as a function. Some parameters are not used at the moment, work for later :)

```
def readBin(file, fun, n, size, endian, signed):
    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        r = []
        count = 0
        byte = f.read(4)
        while count < n and byte != b"":
            i = int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder=endian, signed=signed)
            r.append(i)
            count += 1
            byte = f.read(4)
            byte = f.read(4)
    return r
```

And then here will be the usage:

```
i = readBin('bintest.dat', int, n = 4, size = 8, endian = 'little', signed = False)
print(i)
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Some links for you to examine:

[Working with binary data](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/working-binary-data-python)

[Reading binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this doesn't work. It returns 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: Ok, I've updated the solution. Now it works exactly as your R code.

Comment: `int.from_bytes` does not work in python 2.x. Would one need to use `struct`?