# I want to open bin files that have been saved in opencv into python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

SIFT keypoints in opencv have been saved in a `.bin` file. I want to load the file into Python and use them. The total number of keypoints is 6022451 from 7865 images. I followed [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte), however, there are many solutions and I do not know which one should I follow to read keypoints for each image. I am really confused and a beginner. Could someone please help?