# Handling large binary files in Python

Tags: python, binary

I have a binary file (>1GB in size) which contains single precision data, created in Matlab.

I am new to Python and would like to read the same file structure in Python.

any help would be much appreciated:

From Matlab, I can load the file as follow:

```
fid = fopen('file.dat','r');

my_data = fread(fid,[117276,1794],'single');
```

Many thanks

InP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy is easiest with `fromfile` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html:

```
np.fromfile('file.dat', dtype=np.dtype('single')).reshape((117276, 1794))
```

where `np.dtype('single')` is the same as `np.dtype('float32')`

Note that it may be transposed from what you want since MATLAB reads in column order, while numpy reshapes with row-order.

Also, I'm assuming that using numpy is ok since you are coming from MATLAB and probably will end up using it if you want to keep having MATLAB-like functions and not have to deal with pure python like these answers [Reading binary file and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte)

Comment: Does Matlab add a header or other overhead to the file? Multiplying 117276*1794*4 doesn't reach 1GB.

Comment: Hi Mark, that was mistyping, the actual size is 158616 x 1794 and the file size is 1,138,228,416 bytes. This is 4 times the file dimensions.