# reading files from a folder using os module

Tags: python

for a pattern recognition application, I want to read and operate on jpeg files from another folder using the os module.

I tried to use str(file) and file.encode('latin-1') but they both give me errors

I tried :

```
allLines = []

path = 'results/'
fileList = os.listdir(path)
for file in fileList:
   file = open(os.path.join('results/'+ str(file.encode('latin-1'))), 'r')
   allLines.append(file.read())
print(allLines)
```

but I get an error saying:
No such file or directory "results/b'thefilename"

when I expect a list with the desired file names that are accessible

Comment: Your use of `os.path.join` is not how it's intended. You're doing the join yourself with string concatenation rather than passing it a relative path

Comment: Try `file = open('results/{}'.format(file))` in your `for` loop

Comment: You can’t treat jpeg files as text files that have lines. (And please `close()` your files!)

Comment: You can read from this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Comment: ```file = open('results/{}'.format(file))``` gives me utf-8 error even now

Comment: Something else is going on here. It makes no sense that python returns a string in a format it then can't use immediately afterwards from `os.listdir(path)`.

Comment: Please update the question to show the approach I suggested and include the full traceback

Comment: never mind, I got it @roganjosh

Comment: Why inside the "for" loop do you change the contents of the loop variable `file`?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Python 3.4 or newer, you can use the [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to handle the paths.

```
from pathlib import Path

all_lines = []
path = Path('results/')
for file in path.iterdir():
    with file.open() as f:
        all_lines.append(f.read())
print(all_lines)
```

By using the `with` statement, you don't have to close the file descriptor by hand (what is currently missing), even if an exception is raised at some point.

Comment: still getting an error saying
    all_lines.append(f.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Yes, because someone wrote to you before you use binary data (.jpeg) and they have nothing to do with UTF-8 or another text encoding. These are bytes. You must not understand it as lines, not as text at all. First, you have to determine that this is a binary data `f = open("myfile", "rb")` and secondly you have to work with the buffer if you want to read the data sequentially. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte

Comment: If you actually want to read binary, you can read with 'rb' mode. with `file.open('rb') as f:`