# What the difference between read() and read1() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I am learning python, then I realize there exist a read1() in the python documentation. I am wondering what's the difference between read() and read1()? What the situation we should use read1() instead of read()?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader

Comment: I think this question is on topic. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273111/5267751

Comment: On this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37222446/6282820 the read1 is used, the guy says "Note that we use file.read1. file.read blocks until it gets all the bytes requested of it or EOF. file.read1 allows us to avoid blocking, and it can return more quickly because of this. No other answers mention this as well."
Reading the documentation I could not tell the difference as well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In short, `read([size])` ensures it reads `size` bytes (or until `EOF`) and it may involve multiple reads on the underlying IO object if necessary.

`read1([size])` is to get any data (at-most `size` bytes) that is available in the buffer. If no data in buffer then do at-most 1 `read()` to the IO object.

To elaborate:

`read([size]):` if `size` is negative or None, calls the underlying raw stream's `readall()` method which would read until the `EOF` is reached or it's going to block in a non-blocking mode. The underlying raw stream is duck-typed, meaning if it does not have a `readall()`, then multiple calls to raw stream's `read()` is made until `EOF` is reached or it would block.

if the `size` is a positive, `read()` would return the available data from the buffer. If the available data is less than the `size`, then multiple `read()` calls are made to the raw stream until `size` bytes are available or EOF is reached.

`read1([size])` on the other hand returns any data that is available on the buffer even if it less than `size`, If no data is available and `size` is > 0, then it makes at most one `read()` call to the underlying IO object.

if `size` is omitted or < 0, then the `size` of available buffer is used, So no `read()` call performed on the raw stream in this case.