# How to speed-up read_pickle?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle, python-3.7

Need to write and read huge pandas DF. I am using pickle format right now:

- `.to_pickle` to write DF to pickle
- `read_pickle` to read pickle file.

I have couple of issues when pickle file size is huge (2 GB in this case)

1. Read speed is very slow (23 second to read the data)
2. Increasing RAM/core in VM is not improving speed

How can I read it faster? Can I use some other format which is much faster?
Can I leverage parallel processing/more core functionality to read it faster?

Comment: You could try using Protocol 4 when you create the pickle files, which was available in Python 3.7 but not made the default until Python 3.8.

Comment: 2GiB / 23 sec = 89MiB/sec which is a reasonable maximum speed for spinning rust.

Comment: @martineau: Thanks. Protocol 4 does optimize operation to certain extent. I have started using protocol 4. Improved performance by 7-10%. Although, I am still looking for more improvement.
The total data size is pretty large i.e. close to 100 GB; thus I am looking for faster alternatives. 
Is parquet format faster than pickle format ?

Comment: Dunno about parquet, but @Aaron makes a good point. See the benchmark results in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59013806/355230) to another question that shows the kind of speeds that can achieved just reading plain old binary data files. Maybe the answer is to use a SSD.